# Install dependencies globally and locally using package.json

Tags: node.js, npm

Using npm we can install the modules globally using `-g` option. How can we do this in the package.json file?

Suppose, these are my dependencies in package.json file

```
"dependencies": {
    "mongoose": "1.4.0",
    "node.io" : "0.3.3",
    "jquery"  : "1.5.1",
    "jsdom"   : "0.2.0",
    "cron"    : "0.1.2"
  }
```

When i run `npm install`, I want only `node.io` to be installed globally, the rest others should be installed locally. Is there an option for this?

Comment: You can't. You can however set `"preferGlobal": true` inside package.json for a module.

Comment: yeah, I know about <code>preferGlobal</code>, but that would install all the dependencies globally... anyway Thanks! i guess there is no feature like that...

Comment: I don't think it does. It installs the current module globallly. If an individual dependency has it set to true it may also be installed globally. Really you should just ask @isaacs in #node.js

Comment: Global installations can produce dependency hell. Say package A needs version 0.3.3 and package B version 0.3.4 and both don't work with the other version. Then you'd need two machines to accomodate the two packages.

Comment: none of these comments help me with this issue... it would be nice if you code show me more than just ```"preferGlobal":true```... i don't really know where to put this in package.json. https://npmjs.org/doc/json.html The NPM documentation says that preferGlobal is for your own package and that setting it will make it install your own package as a global. it seems like more of a guide, though.

Answer (score 235, accepted):

**New Note:** You probably don't want or need to do this.  What you probably want to do is just put those types of command dependencies for build/test etc. in the `devDependencies` section of your package.json.  **Anytime you use something from `scripts` in package.json your devDependencies commands (in node_modules/.bin) act as if they are in your path.**

For example:

```
npm i --save-dev mocha # Install test runner locally
npm i --save-dev babel # Install current babel locally
```

Then in package.json:

```
// devDependencies has mocha and babel now

"scripts": {
  "test": "mocha",
  "build": "babel -d lib src",
  "prepublish": "babel -d lib src"
}
```

Then at your command prompt you can run:

```
npm run build # finds babel
npm test # finds mocha

npm publish # will run babel first
```

**New NEW Note**: For awhile now we have had `npx`, which allows you to run the devDependencies commands without needing to add them to your `scripts` section (if you want).
For example:

```
npx webpack
```

*But* if you *really* want to install globally, you can add a preinstall in the scripts section of the package.json:

```
"scripts": {
  "preinstall": "npm i -g themodule"
}
```

So actually my npm install executes npm install again ... Which is weird but seems to work.

**Note:** you might have issues if you are using the most common setup for `npm` where  global Node package installs required `sudo`.  One option is to change your `npm` configuration so this isn't necessary:

`npm config set prefix ~/npm`, add $HOME/npm/bin to $PATH by appending `export PATH=$HOME/npm/bin:$PATH` to your `~/.bashrc`.

Another, probably better option is to just use `nvm` to manage Node and you won't have that problem.

Comment: I wasn't able to get this to work with ```npm i -g underscore-cli```. it gives a warning about wd being wrong. wd means working directory, i guess. when i manually do this on the command line then things go well, however i would prefer if the user were able to deal with installing my code with a simple ```npm install```

Comment: PPPaul -- I had the same problem when I tried this trick again recently.  Maybe my setup is different now or it only works with certain modules.  Otherwise I guess something changed with npm?

Comment: In addition to that you can pre-check if the package is already installed: `npm list module -g || npm install module -g` as npm will return proper exit values.

Comment: How would I run multiple cli instructions?

Comment: Now `npm` needs the `--unsafe-perm` option added to it, since by default it tries to downgrade privileges when executing scripts.  See https://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues/3497.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai: This should really be a separate question.  But, you put your commands in a script, and specify the script as the command to execute (like `"preinstall" : "scripts/preinstall.sh"`).

Comment: @CMCDragonkai concat them with `&&`, for instance `npm install -g bower && npm install -g grunt-cli`

Comment: @m90 - I get an exit code of zero for both global npms that are installed as well as ones that are not - oh, update npm and now it works

Comment: I installed Electron globally instead of as a development dependency because it threw warnings and errors when i tried to install it as such. I think because I was missing some folder? Is there a way I can uninstall the global installation of Electron?

Comment: nevermind. figured it out. pretty straight forward just had to swap install with uninstall in the command lol duhhhhh

Answer (score 12):

**Due to the disadvantages described below, I would recommend** following the accepted answer:

> Use `npm install --save-dev [package_name]` then execute scripts with:
>
> ```
> $ npm run lint
> $ npm run build
> $ npm test
> ```

My original but **not recommended** answer follows.

---

Instead of using a global install, you could add the package to your `devDependencies` (`--save-dev`) and then run the binary from anywhere inside your project:

```
"$(npm bin)/<executable_name>" <arguments>...
```

In your case:

```
"$(npm bin)"/node.io --help
```

[This engineer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9679932/how-to-use-package-installed-locally-in-node-modules#15157360) provided an `npm-exec` alias as a shortcut.  [This engineer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14657170/installing-global-npm-dependencies-via-package-json#14657892) uses a shellscript called `env.sh`. But I prefer to use `$(npm bin)` directly, to avoid any extra file or setup.

Although it makes each call a little larger, it should ***just work***, preventing:

- potential dependency conflicts with global packages (@nalply)
- the need for `sudo`
- the need to set up an npm prefix (although I recommend using one anyway)

Disadvantages:

- `$(npm bin)` won't work on Windows.
- Tools deeper in your dev tree will not appear in the `npm bin` folder. (Install [npm-run](https://github.com/timoxley/npm-run) or [npm-which](https://github.com/timoxley/npm-which) to find them.)

It seems **a better solution** is to place common tasks (such as building and minifying) in the ["scripts" section](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/3738#issuecomment-22505089) of your `package.json`, as Jason demonstrates above.

Comment: Add an alias in your `.bashrc` to easily add the `bin/` directory to your `PATH` environment variable: `alias nodebin='export PATH=$(npm bin)/:$PATH'`. Execute `nodebin` and then you can just type your commands as usual.

Comment: I don't know why it wouldn't work for teams. Of course you need to set it up, and if you don't like to use the alias that's your choice. But it can't hurt to use it in a team.

Answer (score 10):

This is a bit old but I ran into the requirement so here is the solution I came up with.

**The Problem:**

Our development team maintains many .NET web application products we are migrating to AngularJS/Bootstrap. VS2010 does not lend itself easily to custom build processes and my developers are routinely working on multiple releases of our products. Our VCS is Subversion (I know, I know. I'm trying to move to Git but my pesky marketing staff is so demanding) and a single VS solution will include several separate projects. I needed my staff to have a common method for initializing their development environment without having to install the same Node packages (gulp, bower, etc.) several times on the same machine.

**TL;DR:**

1. Need "npm install" to install the global Node/Bower development environment as well as all locally required packages for a .NET product.
2. Global packages should be installed only if not already installed.
3. Local links to global packages must be created automatically.

**The Solution:**

We already have a common development framework shared by all developers and all products so I created a NodeJS script to install the global packages when needed and create the local links. The script resides in "....\SharedFiles" relative to the product base folder:

```
/*******************************************************************************
* $Id: npm-setup.js 12785 2016-01-29 16:34:49Z sthames $
* ==============================================================================
* Parameters: 'links' - Create links in local environment, optional.
* 
* <p>NodeJS script to install common development environment packages in global
* environment. <c>packages</c> object contains list of packages to install.</p>
* 
* <p>Including 'links' creates links in local environment to global packages.</p>
* 
* <p><b>npm ls -g --json</b> command is run to provide the current list of 
* global packages for comparison to required packages. Packages are installed 
* only if not installed. If the package is installed but is not the required 
* package version, the existing package is removed and the required package is 
* installed.</p>.
*
* <p>When provided as a "preinstall" script in a "package.json" file, the "npm
* install" command calls this to verify global dependencies are installed.</p>
*******************************************************************************/
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var fs   = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

/*---------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* List of packages to install and 'from' value to pass to 'npm  */
/* install'. Value must match the 'from' field in 'npm ls -json' */
/* so this script will recognize a package is already installed. */
/*---------------------------------------------------------------*/
var packages = 
  {
  "bower"                      :                      "bower@1.7.2", 
  "event-stream"               :               "event-stream@3.3.2",
  "gulp"                       :                       "gulp@3.9.0",
  "gulp-angular-templatecache" : "gulp-angular-templatecache@1.8.0",
  "gulp-clean"                 :                 "gulp-clean@0.3.1", 
  "gulp-concat"                :                "gulp-concat@2.6.0",
  "gulp-debug"                 :                 "gulp-debug@2.1.2",
  "gulp-filter"                :                "gulp-filter@3.0.1",
  "gulp-grep-contents"         :         "gulp-grep-contents@0.0.1",
  "gulp-if"                    :                    "gulp-if@2.0.0", 
  "gulp-inject"                :                "gulp-inject@3.0.0", 
  "gulp-minify-css"            :            "gulp-minify-css@1.2.3",
  "gulp-minify-html"           :           "gulp-minify-html@1.0.5",
  "gulp-minify-inline"         :         "gulp-minify-inline@0.1.1",
  "gulp-ng-annotate"           :           "gulp-ng-annotate@1.1.0",
  "gulp-processhtml"           :           "gulp-processhtml@1.1.0",
  "gulp-rev"                   :                   "gulp-rev@6.0.1",
  "gulp-rev-replace"           :           "gulp-rev-replace@0.4.3",
  "gulp-uglify"                :                "gulp-uglify@1.5.1",
  "gulp-useref"                :                "gulp-useref@3.0.4",
  "gulp-util"                  :                  "gulp-util@3.0.7",
  "lazypipe"                   :                   "lazypipe@1.0.1",
  "q"                          :                          "q@1.4.1",
  "through2"                   :                   "through2@2.0.0",

  /*---------------------------------------------------------------*/
  /* fork of 0.2.14 allows passing parameters to main-bower-files. */
  /*---------------------------------------------------------------*/
  "bower-main"                 : "git+https://github.com/Pyo25/bower-main.git" 
  }

/*******************************************************************************
* run */
/**
* Executes <c>cmd</c> in the shell and calls <c>cb</c> on success. Error aborts.
* 
* Note: Error code -4082 is EBUSY error which is sometimes thrown by npm for 
* reasons unknown. Possibly this is due to antivirus program scanning the file 
* but it sometimes happens in cases where an antivirus program does not explain 
* it. The error generally will not happen a second time so this method will call 
* itself to try the command again if the EBUSY error occurs.
* 
* @param  cmd  Command to execute.
* @param  cb   Method to call on success. Text returned from stdout is input.
*******************************************************************************/
var run = function(cmd, cb)
  {
  /*---------------------------------------------*/
  /* Increase the maxBuffer to 10MB for commands */
  /* with a lot of output. This is not necessary */
  /* with spawn but it has other issues.         */
  /*---------------------------------------------*/
  exec(cmd, { maxBuffer: 1000*1024 }, function(err, stdout)
    {
    if      (!err)                   cb(stdout);
    else if (err.code | 0 == -4082) run(cmd, cb);
    else throw err;
    });
  };

/*******************************************************************************
* runCommand */
/**
* Logs the command and calls <c>run</c>.
*******************************************************************************/
var runCommand = function(cmd, cb)
  {
  console.log(cmd);
  run(cmd, cb);
  }

/*******************************************************************************
* Main line
*******************************************************************************/
var doLinks  = (process.argv[2] || "").toLowerCase() == 'links';
var names    = Object.keys(packages);
var name;
var installed;
var links;

/*------------------------------------------*/
/* Get the list of installed packages for   */
/* version comparison and install packages. */
/*------------------------------------------*/
console.log('Configuring global Node environment...')
run('npm ls -g --json', function(stdout)
  {
  installed = JSON.parse(stdout).dependencies || {};
  doWhile();
  });

/*--------------------------------------------*/
/* Start of asynchronous package installation */
/* loop. Do until all packages installed.     */
/*--------------------------------------------*/
var doWhile = function()
  {
  if (name = names.shift())
    doWhile0();
  }

var doWhile0 = function()
  {
  /*----------------------------------------------*/
  /* Installed package specification comes from   */
  /* 'from' field of installed packages. Required */
  /* specification comes from the packages list.  */
  /*----------------------------------------------*/
  var current  = (installed[name] || {}).from;
  var required =   packages[name];

  /*---------------------------------------*/
  /* Install the package if not installed. */
  /*---------------------------------------*/
  if (!current)
    runCommand('npm install -g '+required, doWhile1);

  /*------------------------------------*/
  /* If the installed version does not  */
  /* match, uninstall and then install. */
  /*------------------------------------*/
  else if (current != required)
    {
    delete installed[name];
    runCommand('npm remove -g '+name, function() 
      {
      runCommand('npm remove '+name, doWhile0);
      });
    }

  /*------------------------------------*/
  /* Skip package if already installed. */
  /*------------------------------------*/
  else
    doWhile1();
  };

var doWhile1 = function()
  {
  /*-------------------------------------------------------*/
  /* Create link to global package from local environment. */
  /*-------------------------------------------------------*/
  if (doLinks && !fs.existsSync(path.join('node_modules', name)))
    runCommand('npm link '+name, doWhile);
  else
    doWhile();
  };
```

Now if I want to update a global tool for our developers, I update the "packages" object and check in the new script. My developers check it out and either run it with "node npm-setup.js" or by "npm install" from any of the products under development to update the global environment. The whole thing takes 5 minutes.

In addition, to configure the environment for the a new developer, they must first only install NodeJS and GIT for Windows, reboot their computer, check out the "Shared Files" folder and any products under development, and start working.

The "package.json" for the .NET product calls this script prior to install:

```
{ 
"name"                    : "Books",
"description"             : "Node (npm) configuration for Books Database Web Application Tools",
"version"                 : "2.1.1",
"private"                 : true,
"scripts":
  {
  "preinstall"            : "node ../../SharedFiles/npm-setup.js links",
  "postinstall"           : "bower install"
  },
"dependencies": {}
}
```

**Notes**

- Note the script reference requires forward slashes even in a Windows
  environment.
- "npm ls" will give "npm ERR! extraneous:" messages for all packages
  locally linked because they are not listed in the "package.json"
  "dependencies".

**Edit 1/29/16**

The updated `npm-setup.js` script above has been modified as follows:

- Package "version" in `var packages` is now the "package" value passed to `npm install` on the command line. This was changed to allow for installing packages from somewhere other than the registered repository.
- If the package is already installed but is not the one requested, the existing package is removed and the correct one installed.
- For reasons unknown, npm will periodically throw an EBUSY error (-4082) when performing an install or link. This error is trapped and the command re-executed. The error rarely happens a second time and seems to always clear up.

Comment: This is a lifesaver @sthames42 !
I've been trolling for hours trying to figure out exactly how to do this. Clear, comprehensive, generally awesome. #points

Questions: 
(a) Why is Bower in the postinstall when it's already in the packages list?
(b) How to NOT locally link the global packages? Just don't include "links" in the command?

Comment: @MaxRocket: Glad I could help. I have updated the answer to include my latest which works much better. Answers: (a) the 'bower install' command runs after 'npm install' is done to install the Bower components listed in the bower.json file not shown here. I wanted my people to be able to type 'npm install' and have their environment fully set up without having to type another command. (b) Yes.

Comment: The current version of this script is now maintained [here](https://github.com/softlife/npm-global.git).

Answer (score 9):

You could use a separate file, like `npm_globals.txt`, instead of `package.json`. This file would contain each module on a new line like this,

```
mongoose@1.4.0
node.io@0.3.3
jquery@1.5.1
jsdom@0.2.0
cron@0.1.2
```

Then in the command line run,

```
< npm_globals.txt xargs npm install -g
```

Check that they installed properly with,

```
npm list -g --depth=0
```

---

As for whether you *should* do this or not, I think it all depends on use case. For most projects, this isn't necessary; and having your project's `package.json` encapsulate these tools and dependencies together is much preferred.

<del>But nowadays I find that I'm always installing `create-react-app` and other CLI's globally when I jump on a new machine. It's nice to have an easy way to install a global tool and its dependencies when versioning doesn't matter much.</del>

And nowadays, I'm using [`npx`](https://github.com/npm/npx), [an npm package runner](https://medium.com/@maybekatz/introducing-npx-an-npm-package-runner-55f7d4bd282b), instead of installing packages globally.

Comment: This is similar to Python `pip` installing packages based on a `requirements` file. Even if there is `npx` now, you might still need to install packages globally like in Docker. A txt file like this makes sure you can install the exact same set of packages locally or globally.

Answer (score 6):

Build your own script to install global dependencies. It doesn't take much. package.json is quite expandable.

```
const { execSync } = require('child_process');
const fs = require('fs');

const package = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('package.json'));

let keys = Object.keys(package.dependencies);
let values = Object.values(package.dependencies);


for (let index = 0; index < keys.length; index++) {
    const key = keys[index];
    let value = values[index].replace("~", "").replace("^", "");

    console.log(`Installing: ${key}@${value} globally`,);
    execSync('npm i -g ' + `${key}@${value}`);
}
```

Using the above, you can even make it inline, below!

Look at preinstall below:

```
{
  "name": "Project Name",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "Project Description",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "preinstall": "node -e \"const {execSync} = require('child_process'); JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('package.json')).globalDependencies.forEach(globaldep => execSync('npm i -g ' + globaldep));\"",
    "build": "your transpile/compile script",
    "start": "node app.js",
    "test": "./node_modules/.bin/mocha --reporter spec",
    "patch-release": "npm version patch && npm publish && git add . && git commit -m \"auto-commit\" && git push --follow-tags"
  },
  "dependencies": [
  },
  "globalDependencies": [
    "cordova@8.1.2",
    "ionic",
    "potato"
  ],
  "author": "author",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "mocha": "^5.2.0"
  },
  "bin": {
    "app": "app.js"
  }
}
```

The authors of node may not admit package.json is a project file. But it is.

Comment: I like your solution and made some changes to the script so that it works directly with the actual dependencies. I hope this is fine for you.

Comment: Shouldn't `foreach` be `forEach`?

Answer (score 3):

All modules from package.json are installed to ./node_modules/

I couldn't find this explicitly stated but this is the package.json reference for [NPM](https://github.com/isaacs/npm/blob/master/doc/files/package.json.md).

Answer (score 0):

This probably may be door for problems in production.
if project dependencies installed outside project folder, the code may break if anybody else delete or replace your packages or change folder permissions.

Having every thing in one folder is more durable and make system predictable and maintenance tasks easier.