# How to use executables from a package installed locally in node_modules?

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, npm, node-modules

How do I use a local version of a module in `node.js`. For example, in my app, I installed coffee-script:

```
npm install coffee-script
```

This installs it in `./node_modules` and the coffee command is in `./node_modules/.bin/coffee`. Is there a way to run this command when I'm in my project's main folder? I guess I'm looking for something similar to `bundle exec` in bundler. Basically, I'd like to specify a version of coffee-script that everyone involved with the project should use.

I know I can add the `-g` flag to install it globally so coffee works fine anywhere, but what if I wanted to have different versions of coffee per project?

Comment: A lot of instructions I read say things like `npm install niftycommand` and then `niftycommand`. But this will never work unless you have ./node_modules/.bin in your path, will it?

Comment: There is a very good writeup here: https://firstdoit.com/no-need-for-globals-using-npm-dependencies-in-npm-scripts-3dfb478908 — Basically it recommends you to put your `coffee` command into the `npm scripts` section, like `"build": "coffee -co target/directory source/directoy", so you can run `npm run build` from the terminal afterwards.

Comment: @BennyNeugebauer indeed, that's what I've been doing lately instead of messing with PATH

Comment: Use `npx` which comes with `npm 5.2.0` https://medium.com/@maybekatz/introducing-npx-an-npm-package-runner-55f7d4bd282b

Answer (score 736, accepted):

### For npm ⩾5.2.0 (update)

As Seyeong Jeong points out in their answer below, since npm 5.2.0 you can use `npx`, which is more convenient:

```
npx [command]
```

### For older versions npm <5.2.0 (old answer)

The problem with putting

```
./node_modules/.bin
```

into your PATH is that it only works when your current working directory is the root of your project directory structure (i.e. the location of `node_modules`)

Independent of what your working directory is, you can get the path of locally installed binaries with

```
npm bin
```

To execute a locally installed `coffee` binary independent of where you are in the project directory hierarchy you can use this bash construct

```
PATH=$(npm bin):$PATH coffee
```

I aliased this to npm-exec

```
alias npm-exec='PATH=$(npm bin):$PATH'
```

So, now I can

```
npm-exec coffee
```

to run the correct copy of coffee no matter of where I am

```
$ pwd
/Users/regular/project1

$ npm-exec which coffee
/Users/regular/project1/node_modules/.bin/coffee

$ cd lib/
$ npm-exec which coffee
/Users/regular/project1/node_modules/.bin/coffee

$ cd ~/project2
$ npm-exec which coffee
/Users/regular/project2/node_modules/.bin/coffee
```

Comment: you can even go one step further and `alias coffee="npm-exec coffee"`

Comment: `npm bin` isn't independent of the current working directory, though; its output changes based on what the current directory is. Perhaps you meant `npm bin -g`?

Comment: The output changes when you cd into another project. It does not change when you cd within a project. `npm bin` searches the chain of 'ancestor directories' to the cwd for a node_modules directory. This is exactly the desired behavior if you specifically want to use the binaries of modules listed in the project's package.json.

Comment: It would be nice if one could somehow automatically update the PATH variable whenever PWD changes (that is, to remove the need for `npm-exec`)...

Comment: Update: See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19899975/742156) for a solution that automatically updates $PATH transparently.

Comment: @SyntheCypher, I am no winodws user, but did you try cygwin? In the cygwin shell it should work just the same.

Comment: the only problem with this solution is that every time you use the command you extend the path.

Comment: oh gosh! do I really have to do something like that in order to have my local modules working? it's quite impracticable to explain it to a team! there's nothing a little bit more straightforward?

Comment: You can always use [npm scripts](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script) since they always search the local binaries first. You can set up aliases to each of your binaries there or just use generic names like "build".

Comment: @philosodad, actually no, you don't. The `PATH` will be back to what it was before the command invocation. Setting an environment variable in the same line, before running a command only affects that command's environment.

Comment: You can also program these scripts into your package.json scripts section, which does not require altering your path.

Comment: @Alexian there's also zxc which simplifies this a bit: https://www.npmjs.com/package/zxc (see my answer below)

Comment: For Windows, here's a .bat file that does the same thing https://gist.github.com/joeyespo/a532500f5615bf3a4bacf1f410407115

Comment: To avoid false positives for doubly-installed binaries in `$PATH`, you should use `PATH=$(npm bin):${$(which node)%/node}` since the binaries in `npm bin` need the path for `node`.

Comment: This answer is outdated. Either use [npx](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45164863/457268) or [yarn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45633460/457268).

Comment: For Windows users add this to environment path:
```%AppData%\npm```

Comment: the problem with npx is that it downloads dependencies EVERY TIME! (they are already local..)

Comment: So silly this doesn't just work like in yarn

Comment: This answer needs an update for NPM 9, which [removed](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-10-24-npm-v9-0-0-released/) the `npm bin` command. The release note says to use `npx` going forward. Note that the [current version](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/commands/npx?v=true) of `npx` no longer reinstalls packages if they're already installed locally. If you don't like using the officially recommended `npx` command, you could probably still create a solution using `npm root`, but this answer would need an update either way.

Answer (score 624):

[image: Nice example]

You don't have to manipulate `$PATH` anymore!

From [npm@5.2.0](https://github.com/npm/npm/releases/tag/v5.2.0), **npm** ships with `npx` package which lets you run commands from a local `node_modules/.bin` or from a central cache.

Simply run:

```
$ npx [options] <command>[@version] [command-arg]...
```

By default, `npx` will check whether `<command>` exists in `$PATH`, or in the local project binaries, and execute that.

Calling `npx <command>` when `<command>` isn't already in your `$PATH` will automatically install a package with that name from the NPM registry for you, and invoke it. When it's done, the installed package won’t be anywhere in your globals, so you won’t have to worry about pollution in the long-term. You can prevent this behaviour by providing `--no-install` option.

For `npm < 5.2.0`, you can install `npx` package manually by running the following command:

```
$ npm install -g npx
```

Comment: I dont like installing 3rd party global npm packages while `npm` and `package.json` provides nearly same functionality.

Comment: If "Path must be a string. Received undefined" message appears, here is a fix: https://github.com/zkat/npx/issues/144#issuecomment-391031816

Comment: This answer is good. But I just want to say `npx` is lame. It should have been `npm run` or `npm exec` or something.

Comment: @WilliamEntriken For some reasons, `npm run [my-local-package]` isn't working on my Ubuntu, although it seemed to work on a Windows device.

Comment: This answer should also include how to register a binary in a package.json file for publishers, https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/package-json#bin

Comment: Strangely this answer includes one (and only one?) paragraph verbatim -- ha, **the image used in this answer is also a dupe** -- from [this blog post](https://medium.com/@maybekatz/introducing-npx-an-npm-package-runner-55f7d4bd282b#aefb). Can't tell who was first, though I have my guesses. `;^D` Either way, that blog provides a lot of context.

Comment: @WilliamEntriken It is in fact `npm exec`; `npx` is just a shortcut to that. A safe version of this command when you want to run some command in the current project is `npm exec --no packagename -- [options]` (or `npx --no packagename -- [options]`). The `--no` will prevent it from magically installing `packagename` if it isn't already installed, thus avoiding security risks from typo-squatting etc.

Answer (score 123):

**No longer works - removed: https://github.com/npm/cli/pull/6289**

Use the `npm bin` command to get the node modules /bin directory of your project

```
$ $(npm bin)/<binary-name> [args]
```

e.g.

```
$ $(npm bin)/bower install
```

Comment: I like this simple and generic solution. Makes an alias seem unnecessary.

Comment: Seems to be the next best solution that is elegant and more secure than having to do `export PATH="./node_modules/.bin:$PATH"`

Comment: @inf3rno the command is `$(npm bin)/jasmine`, not `node $(npm bin)/jasmine` (you probably figured it out but clarifying for others).

Comment: Not a bad solution, but it doesn't run on a standard windows command line with $. Putting it in the package.json scripts section is a better approach I feel, since it's more compatible.

Answer (score 85):

Use `npm run[-script] <script name>`

After using npm to install the bin package to your local `./node_modules` directory, modify `package.json` to add `<script name>` like this:

```
$ npm install --save learnyounode
$ edit packages.json
>>> in packages.json
...
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "learnyounode": "learnyounode"
},
...
$ npm run learnyounode
```

*It would be nice if npm install had a --add-script option or something or if npm run would work without adding to the scripts block.*

Comment: I found this approach to be more uniform when dealing with multiple developers on a project - it avoids the need to configure anything locally... you just `npm install` then you have access to your dev dependencies. The only minor down side is you need to `npm run eslint` (or whatever). You can create a script called "start" that runs gulp so that you only need to type `npm start` to start your dev server. Pretty cool stuff and no bash goodness, so your windows friends still like you. :)

Comment: adding an alias to put $(npm bin) on your path is clever, but the fact that this will work for people without local config wins my heart

Comment: this needs more upvotes! Pass args to your scripts after `--` like: `npm run learnyounode -- --normal-switches --watch -d *.js`

Comment: I also find this the best solution. There is an in-depth explanation here: https://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/04/24/executing-a-project-specific-nodenpm-package-a-la-bundle-exec/

Comment: This is what I usually go for, but for some reasons, on an Ubuntu device, `npm run ts-node` isn't working for me. I'll just have to ressort to npx.

Comment: I went googlging to come to this question exactly because I don't want to use package.json scripts. IN particular, I don't want to put my commands in a package.json file when my project comprises multiple languages and frameworks. Putting commands in package.json makes it inconsistent with other languages.

Answer (score 64):

## update: If you're on the recent npm (version >5.2)

You can use:

```
npx <command>
```

`npx` looks for command in `.bin` directory of your `node_modules`

## old answer:

## For Windows

Store the following in a file called `npm-exec.bat` and add it to your `%PATH%`

```
@echo off
set cmd="npm bin"
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%i IN (' %cmd% ') DO SET modules=%%i
"%modules%"\%*
```

### Usage

Then you can use it like
`npm-exec <command> <arg0> <arg1> ...`

**For example**

To execute `wdio` installed in local node_modules directory, do:

```
npm-exec wdio wdio.conf.js
```

i.e. it will run  `.\node_modules\.bin\wdio wdio.conf.js`

Comment: This doesn't work while passing more than 1 argument. E.g. npm-exec gulp <some_task>

Comment: @OK9999 I'm sure some minor modification will allow passing arguments (because when you pass it here, it's coming in quoted in ""); What I suggest is copy paste the gulp file from bin to your project root (some modifications needed of the file, but it will just work without writing new code etc)

Comment: Yes, i ended up doing so. The node_modules folder have to be in the folder where the gulpfile exist

Answer (score 45):

**Update:** I no longer recommend this method, both for the mentioned security reasons and not the least the newer `npm bin` command. Original answer below:

As you have found out, any locally installed binaries are in `./node_modules/.bin`. In order to always run binaries in this directory rather than globally available binaries, if present, I suggest you put `./node_modules/.bin` first in your path:

```
export PATH="./node_modules/.bin:$PATH"
```

If you put this in your `~/.profile`, `coffee` will always be `./node_modules/.bin/coffee` if available, otherwise `/usr/local/bin/coffee` (or whatever prefix you are installing node modules under).

Comment: that's probably the best solution. I also created a bash script called "watch" in my project: `./node_modules/.bin/coffee --output lib/ --compile --bare --watch src`

Comment: Danger, Will Robinson! Use of relative paths in your $PATH opens up a security hole the size of a planet, especially if you put them right up front as the first item. If the directory you're in is writable by everyone (say somewhere in `/tmp`), any process or user can hijack your session by putting malicious versions of ordinary commands (like `ls`, `cp`, etc.) there. These may spawn 'invisible' sub-shells capturing your passwords, etcetera.

Comment: will only work in the root and no other places. the `alias npm-exec='PATH=$(npm bin):$PATH'` is slicker.

Comment: How bad is this if you don't put it as the first thing in your `PATH`, but the last (using the `$(npm bin)` form)? so they can't overwrite your existing stuff, and you would have been trusting the executables in the `npm bin` directory already regardless of the `PATH` var; would the threat model be that a) someone malicious gets access to your file system, b) they add executables with names that are close to those system tools, and c) you mistype?

Trying to understand scenarios that make this bad, given that you're already trusting foreign executables when using `npm`-installed programs.

Comment: You can do shell tricks with an alias and you can path manually and this "works" but it is not quite ideal.

Answer (score 43):

Use [`npm-run`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-run).

From the readme:

## npm-run

#### Find & run local executables from node_modules

Any executable available to an npm lifecycle script is available to `npm-run`.

### Usage

```
$ npm install mocha # mocha installed in ./node_modules
$ npm-run mocha test/* # uses locally installed mocha executable
```

### Installation

```
$ npm install -g npm-run
```

Comment: No longer, see npx referenced above...
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45164863/3246805

Answer (score 29):

**TL;DR: Use [`npm exec`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-exec) with `npm@>=7`.**

---

The `npx` command which was mentioned in other answers has been completely rewritten in `npm@7` which ships by default with `node@15` and can be installed on `node@>=10`. The implementation is now equal to the newly introduced `npm exec` command, which is similar but not equal to the previous `npx` command implementation.

One difference is e.g. that it always interactively asks if a dependency should be downloaded when it is not already installed (can also be overwritten with the params `--yes` or `--no`).

Here is an example for `npm exec`. The double dashes (`--`) separates the `npm exec` params from the actual command params:

```
npm exec --no -- jest --coverage
```

See also the [updated, official documentation to `npm exec`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-exec).

Comment: "_The implementation is now_ **[nearly]** _equal to the newly introduced npm exec command_" There are some weird backwards compat things in there that make your link to the docs potentially very useful.

Answer (score 25):

If you want to keep npm, then [npx](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45164863/457268) should do what you need.

---

If switching to yarn (a npm replacement by facebook) is an option for you, then you can call:

```
 yarn yourCmd
```

scripts inside the package.json will take precedence, if none is found it will look inside the `./node_modules/.bin/` folder.

It also outputs what it ran:

```
$ yarn tsc
yarn tsc v0.27.5
$ "/home/philipp/rate-pipeline/node_modules/.bin/tsc"
```

So you don't have to setup scripts for each command in your `package.json`.

---

If you had a script defined at `.scripts` inside your `package.json`:

```
"tsc": "tsc" // each command defined in the scripts will be executed from `./node_modules/.bin/` first
```

`yarn tsc` would be equivalent to `yarn run tsc` or `npm run tsc`:

```
 yarn tsc
 yarn tsc v0.27.5
 $ tsc
```

Answer (score 23):

The PATH solution has the issue that if $(npm bin) is placed in your .profile/.bashrc/etc it is evaluated once and is forever set to whichever directory the path was first evaluated in. If instead you modify the current path then every time you run the script your path will grow.

To get around these issues, I create a function and used that. It doesn't modify your environment and is simple to use:

```
function npm-exec {
   $(npm bin)/$@  
}
```

This can then be used like this without making any changes to your environment:

```
npm-exec r.js <args>
```

Comment: I like this! I simply named my function `n`

Answer (score 12):

I prefer to not rely on shell aliases or another package.

Adding a simple line to `scripts` section of your `package.json`, you can run local npm commands like

`npm run webpack`

**package.json**

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "webpack": "webpack"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^4.1.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.0.11"
  }
}
```

Comment: This gets ugly when you want to pass arguments to webpack.

For example `npm run webpack --is thos --possible`

Answer (score 6):

If you want your PATH variable to correctly update based on your current working directory, add this to the end of your `.bashrc`-equivalent (or after anything that defines `PATH`):

```
__OLD_PATH=$PATH
function updatePATHForNPM() {
  export PATH=$(npm bin):$__OLD_PATH
}

function node-mode() {
  PROMPT_COMMAND=updatePATHForNPM
}

function node-mode-off() {
  unset PROMPT_COMMAND
  PATH=$__OLD_PATH
}

# Uncomment to enable node-mode by default:
# node-mode
```

This may add a short delay every time the bash prompt gets rendered (depending on the size of your project, most likely), so it's disabled by default.

You can enable and disable it within your terminal by running `node-mode` and `node-mode-off`, respectively.

Answer (score 6):

I've always used the same approach as @guneysus to solve this problem, which is creating a script in the package.json file and use it running npm run script-name.

However, in the recent months I've been using [npx](https://github.com/zkat/npx#readme) and I love it.

For example, I downloaded an Angular project and I didn't want to install the Angular CLI globally. So, with npx installed, instead of using the global angular cli command (if I had installed it) like this:

```
ng serve
```

I can do this from the console:

```
npx ng serve
```

[Here's an article](https://medium.com/@jaireina/npx-makes-npm-nicer-and-even-more-useful-50086375ee6c?source=friends_link&sk=58c916f5e77a61f12ecbfa37810e69c7) I wrote about NPX and that goes deeper into it.

Answer (score 3):

## Answer 2023:

### Old Solution: `$(npm bin)/package`

The correct answer used to be `$(npm bin)/package-name` until npm [removed](https://github.com/npm/statusboard/issues/537) it in version 9 (around August 2022).

### New Solution `npm exec -- package`

The new solution that Node recommends is `npx` or `npm exec` which are [slightly different](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-exec#npx-vs-npm-exec). I tried following that doc, but the only format that worked perfectly for me was `npm exec -- package-name -x ...` which would properly convey the parameters to the `package-name`.

Weirdly, using `npx` (with or without `--`) was prompting me to install `run` npm package, which is [an 8-year-old irrelevant package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/run)!

### TL;DR

Upgrading from Node 16 to Node 20, in my `package.json` I needed to replace

```json
{
        "build-prod": "npm run clean && $(npm bin)/npm-run-all -s _build:*"
}
```

with

```json
{
        "build-prod": "npm run clean && npm exec -- npm-run-all -s _build:*"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Same @regular 's accepted solution, but Fish shell flavour

```
if not contains (npm bin) $PATH
    set PATH (npm bin) $PATH
end
```

Answer (score 1):

[zxc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/zxc) is like "bundle exec" for nodejs. It is similar to using `PATH=$(npm bin):$PATH`:

```
$ npm install -g zxc
$ npm install gulp
$ zxc which gulp
/home/nathan/code/project1/node_modules/.bin/gulp
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use direnv and change the $PATH variable only in your working folder.

```
$ cat .envrc
> export PATH=$(npm bin):$PATH
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this script to your `.bashrc`. Then you can call `coffee` or anyhting locally. This is handy for your laptop, but don't use it on your server.

```
DEFAULT_PATH=$PATH;

add_local_node_modules_to_path(){
  NODE_MODULES='./node_modules/.bin';
  if [ -d $NODE_MODULES ]; then
    PATH=$DEFAULT_PATH:$NODE_MODULES;
  else
    PATH=$DEFAULT_PATH;
  fi
}

cd () {
  builtin cd "$@";
  add_local_node_modules_to_path;
}

add_local_node_modules_to_path;
```

*note*: this script makes aliase of `cd` command, and after each call of `cd` it checks `node_modules/.bin` and add it to your `$PATH`.

*note2*: you can change the third line to `NODE_MODULES=$(npm bin);`. But that would make `cd` command too slow.

Comment: Use `$(npm bin)` instead of hardcoding `./node_modules/.bin`.

Comment: Hmm, `$(npm bin)` seems too slow to use with each `cd` command. I've restore the code and added a note for it.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows use this:

```
/* cmd into "node_modules" folder */
"%CD%\.bin\grunt" --version
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem and I don't particularly like using aliases (as [regular](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1196043/regular)'s suggested), and if you don't like them too then here's another workaround that I use, you first have to create a tiny executable bash script, say **setenv.sh**:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Add your local node_modules bin to the path
export PATH="$(npm bin):$PATH"

# execute the rest of the command
exec "$@"
```

and then you can then use any executables in your local `/bin` using this command:

```
./setenv.sh <command>
./setenv.sh 6to5-node server.js
./setenv.sh grunt
```

If you're using `scripts` in package.json then:

```
...,
scripts: {
    'start': './setenv.sh <command>'
}
```

Comment: this setenv script isn't necessary for package.json scripts. npm already prepends the local node_modules/.bin directory to path for you when executing npm run {scripts}.

Answer (score 0):

I'd love to know if this is an insecure/bad idea, but after thinking about it a bit I don't see an issue here:

Modifying Linus's insecure solution to add it to the end, using `npm bin` to find the directory, and making the script only call `npm bin` when a `package.json` is present in a parent (for speed), this is what I came up with for `zsh`:

```
find-up () {
  path=$(pwd)
  while [[ "$path" != "" && ! -e "$path/$1" ]]; do
    path=${path%/*}
  done
  echo "$path"
}

precmd() {
  if [ "$(find-up package.json)" != "" ]; then
    new_bin=$(npm bin)
    if [ "$NODE_MODULES_PATH" != "$new_bin" ]; then
      export PATH=${PATH%:$NODE_MODULES_PATH}:$new_bin
      export NODE_MODULES_PATH=$new_bin
    fi
  else
    if [ "$NODE_MODULES_PATH" != "" ]; then
      export PATH=${PATH%:$NODE_MODULES_PATH}
      export NODE_MODULES_PATH=""
    fi
  fi
}
```

For `bash`, instead of using the `precmd` hook, you can use the `$PROMPT_COMMAND` variable (I haven't tested this but you get the idea):

```
__add-node-to-path() {
  if [ "$(find-up package.json)" != "" ]; then
    new_bin=$(npm bin)
    if [ "$NODE_MODULES_PATH" != "$new_bin" ]; then
      export PATH=${PATH%:$NODE_MODULES_PATH}:$new_bin
      export NODE_MODULES_PATH=$new_bin
    fi
  else
    if [ "$NODE_MODULES_PATH" != "" ]; then
      export PATH=${PATH%:$NODE_MODULES_PATH}
      export NODE_MODULES_PATH=""
    fi
  fi   
}

export PROMPT_COMMAND="__add-node-to-path"
```

Comment: Adding `npm bin` to end of `$PATH` may not execute what user expects:
 basically another executable but more probably a globally installed package with another version !

Answer (score 0):

I am a `Windows` user and this is what worked for me:

```
// First set some variable - i.e. replace is with "xo"
D:\project\root> set xo="./node_modules/.bin/"

// Next, work with it
D:\project\root> %xo%/bower install
```

Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using `fish shell` and do not want to add to `$path` for security reason. We can add the below function to run local node executables.

```
### run executables in node_module/.bin directory
function n 
  set -l npmbin (npm bin)   
  set -l argvCount (count $argv)
  switch $argvCount
    case 0
      echo please specify the local node executable as 1st argument
    case 1
      # for one argument, we can eval directly 
      eval $npmbin/$argv
    case '*'
      set --local executable $argv[1]
      # for 2 or more arguments we cannot append directly after the $npmbin/ since the fish will apply each array element after the the start string: $npmbin/arg1 $npmbin/arg2... 
      # This is just how fish interoperate array. 
      set --erase argv[1]
      eval $npmbin/$executable $argv 
  end
end
```

Now you can run thing like:

`n coffee`

or more arguments like:

`n browser-sync --version`

Note, if you are `bash` user, then @Bob9630 answers is the way to go by leveraging bash's `$@`, which is not available in `fishshell`.

Answer (score -1):

I propose a new solution I have developed (05/2021)

You can use lpx https://www.npmjs.com/package/lpx to

- run a binary found in the local node_modules/.bin folder
- run a binary found in the node_modules/.bin of a workspace root from anywhere in the workspace

lpx does not download any package if the binary is not found locally (ie not like npx)

Example :
`lpx tsc -b -w` will run `tsc -b -w` with the local typescript package

Comment: It's suggested to mention if any linked material is created by you.

Comment: I just tried `lpx`, it doesn't work due to the file using the wrong (Windows) line-endings on the shebang line.

Answer (score -11):

Include coffee-script in package.json with the specific version required in each project, typically like this:

```
"dependencies":{
  "coffee-script": ">= 1.2.0"
```

Then run npm install to install dependencies in each project. This will install the specified version of coffee-script which will be accessible locally to each project.

Comment: yeah, I got that far as I stated in my question. how do I specifically call the one in my project besides ./node_modules/.bin/coffee?

Comment: If you've run npm install with the package.json in your project's main folder, you should have a ./node_modules/.bin/coffee folder in this folder. Using ./node_modules/coffee-script/bin/coffee will run the local version of coffee while just running coffee will run the global installation. If you have another version of coffee installed in another path within this project folder, you can access it using ./path/to/this/installation/coffee.

Comment: This did not work for me.  I am trying to use "svgo", and it only works when installed globally.  I have tried `npm install svgo` as well as `npm install` with package.json.  Both methods installed "successfully", but the "svgo" command is still not available.

Comment: Grunt uses this in a clever way, and IMHO so should other packages. First you install the `grunt-cli` package globally, then in your project directory install any (modified) version of the `grunt` package, then when you run `grunt`, it will use this local version.