# NPM installing modules to application root

Tags: javascript, node.js, unix, npm

I messed something up and I've done my best to fix it, but no luck.

Whenever I run 'npm install' on a new node project, it installs all of my dependencies to the root of the application instead of in /node_modules/ like you'd expect in a default application.

For example-

My package.json

```
{
  "name": "hello-world",
  "description": "hello world test app",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "3.x"
  }
}
```

When I use 'npm install' I end up with this:

[image]

I've tried setting my PATH like in this solution:
[How to use package installed locally in node_modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9679932/how-to-use-package-installed-locally-in-node-modules)

but that didn't seem to do much. Help?

Comment: Can you post the content of your `~/.npmrc`?

Comment: updated- I think you might be on to something!

Comment: What does `/private/tmp/timothy/timothy_local_job_1367532952281_60137/.npmcfg` contain? Also, observe that you have the `cache` variable set in that directory.

Comment: I removed that stuff and the defaults took over. Everything works great! If you post that as an answer you've got my accept.

What does the cache variable do? Should I take that out while I'm in there?

Comment: You answered your own question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> observe that you have the cache variable set in that directory

```
strict-ssl = false
userconfig = /private/tmp/timothy/timothy_local_job_1367532952281_60137/.npmcfg
cache = /Users/tomhorton/Documents/Repository/helpmestackoverflow
root = ./node_modules
```

> That timothy stuff is from a module that I installed shortly before everything went haywire-
>
> I removed that stuff and the defaults took over. Everything works great!