# NPM : how to source ./node_modules/.bin folder?

Tags: node.js, npm, sails.js

I have a problem on npm installation

I have created a project say project A

```
cd ~/projectA
npm install sails
```

but sails command is not found after installation.

I know that it is successfully install in `~/projectA/node_modules` directory.
but the executable cannot be sourced. And i know it is installed `~/projectA/node_modules/.bin`

How can I source the .bin automatically whenever I enter into this projectA folder?

Did I did something wrong?

Comment: Are you sure it is installed under `~/projectA/node_modules/.bin` and not `~/projectA/node_modules/sails/bin` instead? What do you mean by source?

Comment: @verybadalloc source is like the unix dot http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_(Unix) and http://superuser.com/a/46146

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use package installed locally in node\_modules?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9679932/how-to-use-package-installed-locally-in-node-modules)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I can give you an inelegant solution, which is working for me. I just exported my path in my .bashrc file.

```
export PATH="$PATH:./node_modules/.bin"
```

Edit: It's been a while, but I have changed my strategy to use npm scripts instead. In the above case, setup package.json as follows:

```
"scripts": {
    "sails": "sails"
}
```

Which you can then run with

```
npm run sails
```

or with arguments

```
npm run sails -- <args>
```

Comment: I would put the node_modules/.bin first: `export PATH="./node_modules/.bin:$PATH"`

Comment: Upvote for using npm scripts, and for the hint on how to use args

Answer (score 14):

You should use the `npm bin` command to get an absolute path to your current node bin directory.

For example:

```
➤ lessc
bash: lessc: command not found
➤ npm bin
/home/brice/[...]/node_modules/.bin
➤ export PATH=$(npm bin):$PATH
➤ lessc --version
lessc 1.7.3 (Less Compiler) [JavaScript]
```

This avoids the problem of relative paths, especially if you're going to be using this in a build system that will invoke the command in subdirectories.

Answer (score 3):

A bit more robust is:

```
export PATH=$(npm bin):$PATH
```

You can either run it, add it to your shell profile, or create an alias like:

```
alias snpm='export PATH=$(npm bin):$PATH'
```

If you do go the alias route, be sure to use single quotes so it delays the execution of the variables!

Comment: Thanks for the help! 

Answer (score 1):

To use on the command line like `sails generate foo` you will need to install the npm module globally.

```
npm install -g sails
```

You could also use the path to the bin in the command if you don't want to install globally:

```
./node_modules/sails/bin/sails.js generate foo
```

Answer (score 1):

The official instructions for sails (https://github.com/balderdashy/sails) advises

> To install the latest stable release with the command-line tool:

```
sudo npm -g install sails
```

This installs globally and adds to a directory like `/usr/local/bin` that should be in your `$PATH`.

But to answer the general question regarding the location of the binaries if you install locally, they should be placed in `./node_modules/.bin` directory (so run `./node_modules/.bin/sails ...`)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like to mess up with your PATH for running a npm script that isn't global -- e.g. you are the only one to use it --, I would personally recommend the use of an sh "alias".

1. npm install (locally) your beloved package (json-diff here, for instance)

   ```
   cd ~ && npm install json-diff
   ```
2. alias it (save it in your ~/.xxxxrc file):

   ```
   alias diffj "\`npm bin\`/json-diff !*"
   ```

Then, for diffing 2 json's:

```
diffj old.json new.json
```

Answer (score 0):

In my `~/.bashrc`, I have the following:

```
function nbin {
  local dir;
  dir=$(npm bin)
  if [ -d "$dir" ]; then
    ( # subshell to not change this shell's $PATH
      PATH=$dir:$PATH
      eval "$@"
    )
  else
    echo "\"$dir\" is not an npm binary directory." >&1
    return 1
  fi
}
```

I can then run executable `foo` in the `.bin` directory as:

```
nbin foo
```

Answer (score -1):

Possible workaround with NPM 5.2+ using the `npx` command.

```sh
npx sails new test-project
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9679932/) question for a similar use case and elegant solutions.