# How do I install the sequelize.js binary?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am referencing the sequelize.js documentation at:
http://sequelizejs.com/documentation#migrations-the-binary

After running 'sequelize -V', I receive:

```
$ sequelize -V
sequelize: command not found
```

I have searched online and cannot find any references on how to install the binary

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The CLI has moved to `sequelize-cli`:

```
npm install -g sequelize-cli
```

https://github.com/sequelize/cli

Comment: This answer wasn't mentioned for a year after the question had been posted. Was it available at that time?

Comment: Or `yarn global add sequelize-cli`

Answer (score 1):

If you install locally, there are links to binaries at `./node_modules/.bin` . This path applies to all your local binaries, and you can output this on your CLI with `npm bin` .

You can also do `ls -laF node_modules/.bin` to view where the links point to.

See [this stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9679932/how-to-use-package-installed-locally-in-node-modules) for more

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still struggling with all this, let me tell you now in v6 of sequelize you can just do:

```
yarn sequelize init
```

If npm probably this command will be helpfull (though not tested)

```
npx sequelize init
```

NOTE: Later one is not tested so I'm not sure about it.

Answer (score -2):

After installing sequelize.js via

```
npm install sequelize
```

The sequelize binary will be located in your node_modules/sequelize/bin folder. The sequelize binary can be accessed directly or by adding this folder to your environment.

Try "./your/path/node_modules/sequelize/bin/sequlize -V" to verify.

Comment: All you need to do is add the `-g` flag when installing it.

Comment: Neither one of these facts is documented by sequelize's site. Wasted 30 minutes poking around to find it. Following through their site's docs, the installation step doesn't use the global flag.

Comment: @thaspius It would probably help if they mentioned the different installation as well, but it's primarily documented by NPM itself: [`npm-folders(5)`](https://npmjs.org/doc/files/npm-folders.html).

Comment: Its worth noting that at the actual time of the posting, I could not figure the issue out and this answer was actually what fixed it. Downvoting what was at that time an actual legitimate answer seems absurd...