# -bash: sequelize: command not found

Tags: npm, sequelize.js

I just ran npm install --save sequelize pg pg-hstore in my project root directory and now I am unable to invoke sequelize init. I get the error: -bash: sequelize: command not found. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install the sequelize.js binary?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18168312/how-do-i-install-the-sequelize-js-binary)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would like to answer my own question. The global npm install path was wrong for my computer.

> npm config get prefix

Then I ran to put the path where it should be. This problem gave me a lot of head aches. Hope it helps someone.

> npm config set prefix /usr/local

Answer (score 71):

The reason is: sequelize is not installed globally on your cli. To get sequelize access to all your cli just do.

```
npm install -g sequelize-cli
```

The '-g' means global this will allow you to access sequelize command anywhere in your app directory.

After that you can do eg: `sequelize model:generate --name User --attributes firstName:string,lastName:string,email:string,password:string`

Comment: thanks. it's working

Answer (score 29):

I prefer to avoid installing global npm packages. If you have `sequelize` as a dependency in your `package.json`, you can utilize `sequelize-cli` via `npx`.

`$ npx sequelize-cli <command>`.

For example, you could do `$ npx sequelize-cli migration:generate --name add-a-column` to create a migration file.

Comment: Thank you .. adding "npx" solving my issue.

Answer (score 17):

Had the same issue, then noted that `sequelize-cli` is the way to go ahead.

```
npm install -g sequelize-cli
```

Answer (score 8):

I had this problem and solved it by running

```
nvm install node --reinstall-packages-from=node
```

and then reinstalling

```
npm install -g sequelize-cli
```

Before doing this I had an unfortunate Node Version Manager setup. My computer was running something like version 10, but installing sequelize in the path used by version 8.

Now everything is updated and works.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to use `sequelize-cli` without install it globally , you need to run it from `node_modules` folder in your root project. that is `node_modules/.bin/sequelize`. try to run `node_modules/.bin/sequelize help` for more information about sequelize command line

Answer (score 2):

The following steps worked on Pop!_OS 20.10 & ubuntu 20.04

npm install -g sequelize-cli

Answer (score 2):

Problem : Unknown command: "sequelize"
Solve : npx sequelize init

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

first install **npm install sequelize sequelize-cli**
After that run **npx sequelize init** instead of **sequelize init**
That works for me

Answer (score 1):

I also got the message: *zsh: command not found: sequelize* and **npx sequelize init** instead of *sequelize init* solved the problem for me

Answer (score 1):

`npx sequelize-cli <command>`

For the latest version, That works for me.

Answer (score 1):

npm install -g sequelize-cli

this working.
We need to install sequence globally

Answer (score 1):

To resolve the issue, install Sequelize CLI globally using the command:

```
npm install -g sequelize-cli
```

After installation, retry the `sequelize init` command, and it should work as expected.

[Error and after solve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRm18.png)

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. I cd to

```
<proj_dir>\node_modules\sequelize-automate\bin
```

from there I ran

```
node sequelize-automate -t js -h localhost -d <proj_dir> -u postgres -p ****** -P 5432 -e postgres -o root to \src\models
```

command. It worked like charm.

Answer (score 0):

worked on windows os

open powershell as an admistrator after that run following commands:

Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
Get-ExecutionPolicy -List
LSet-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope LocalMachine
after step 3 press A for all

work for me......

Answer (score 0):

if you're using Yarn

```
yarn global add sequelize-cli --prefix /usr/local
```

And run

```
sequelize init
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to initialize a Sequelize project using npm init sequelize, but I encountered an error:

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/create-sequelize - Not found
```

However, I managed to resolve the issue by using
`npx sequelize init`.

When you run npx sequelize init, it's akin to running the locally or globally installed Sequelize CLI's init command, bypassing the need to look for a package like create-sequelize.