# Not found after installing Sequelize-cli globally on MacOS

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I installed Sequelize-cli on MacOS with the following command:

```
1. npm i sequelize mysql2
2. sudo npm i -g sequelize-cli
```

However, when I use the sequelize command, I get the following error:

```
bash: sequelize: command not found
```

I used global when I installed the express-generator and nodemon, but it did not matter.

Why does sequelize only cause problems?

Comment: try implementing without sudo i.e. just `npm i -g sequelize-cli`

Comment: Installing without sudo causes an error.

Comment: There is actually a solution @ [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43099808/bash-sequelize-command-not-found)

Answer (score -1):

worked on windows os

open powershell as an admistrator after that run following commands:

1. Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
2. Get-ExecutionPolicy -List
3. LSet-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope LocalMachine

after step 3 press A for all

work for me......