# how to solve "sequelize: command not found"?

Tags: node.js, terminal, sequelize.js

This is so frustrating.. I am trying to install sequalize for node.js. I installed it locally with success, but I cant install it globally  (I am getting permission denied errors for:

```
 \'../lib/node_modules/sequelize-cli/lib/sequelize\').
```

I actually don't really want it globally installed, but when have it locally and should configure and initialize the sequelize module (by typing ***sequelize init:models & sequelize init:config*** in terminal) I get the following error:

```
-bash: sequelize: command not found
```

So I did my homework and found out that the command not found error could be solved with globally install ([-bash: sequelize: command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43099808/bash-sequelize-command-not-found)) and to fix the error in enabling globally install I changed my user access ([Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules' react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48910876/error-eacces-permission-denied-access-usr-local-lib-node-modules-react)), but this didnt do the trick, I still getting permission denied.

So my question is how could I run ***sequelize init:models & sequelize init:config*** in terminal without getting command not found?

Comment: To install packages globally, most of the times you need root privileges so you need to use sudo and insert your password $sudo npm install -g sequelize.

Comment: It worked! I used sudo on both npm install -g sequelize and npm install sequelize-cli and then it worked. thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [-bash: sequelize: command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43099808/bash-sequelize-command-not-found)

Comment: @vitomadio quick tip: if you have to use sudo when you're using npm, something is wrong. I recommend you get that fixed quickly. That is super dangerous. If someone put a script in their "postinstall" for rm -rf /, it runs automatically after installation, and you've just run it with sudo and given it permission to delete your entire hard drive.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer for my problem was solved with installing it global with the help of sudo as vitamadio said in the comment. So the answear was to install it this way:

```
sudo npm install -g sequelize
```

and then:

```
sudo npm i -g sequelize-cli
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to install

```
npm install --save sequelize
npm install --save sequelize-cli
```

And then according [to documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize-cli) you can run the CLI. No need to install it globally.

```
$ npx sequelize --help

Sequelize CLI [Node: 10.0.0, CLI: 5.5.1, ORM: 5.19.0]

sequelize [command]

Commands:
  sequelize db:migrate                        Run pending migrations
  sequelize db:migrate:schema:timestamps:add  Update migration table to have timestamps
  sequelize db:migrate:status                 List the status of all migrations
  sequelize db:migrate:undo                   Reverts a migration
  sequelize db:migrate:undo:all               Revert all migrations ran
  sequelize db:seed                           Run specified seeder
  sequelize db:seed:undo                      Deletes data from the database
  sequelize db:seed:all                       Run every seeder
  sequelize db:seed:undo:all                  Deletes data from the database
  sequelize db:create                         Create database specified by configuration
  sequelize db:drop                           Drop database specified by configuration
  sequelize init                              Initializes project
  sequelize init:config                       Initializes configuration
  sequelize init:migrations                   Initializes migrations
  sequelize init:models                       Initializes models
  sequelize init:seeders                      Initializes seeders
  sequelize migration:generate                Generates a new migration file   [aliases: migration:create]
  sequelize model:generate                    Generates a model and its migration  [aliases: model:create]
  sequelize seed:generate                     Generates a new seed file             [aliases: seed:create]

Options:
  --help     Show help                                                                           [boolean]
  --version  Show version number                                                                 [boolean]
```

Comment: I have done that, it still says "sequelize: command not found”

Comment: what is the output of this command `npm ls | grep sequelize` ?

Comment: And did you try to run it like this `npx sequelize init:models`?

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your help, I solved it with using sudo on both npm install -g sequelize and npm install sequelize-cli.

Answer (score 4):

You need to install as following:

```
npm install --save sequelize
npm install --save sequelize-cli
```

Also install npx if you don't have it then
Initialize sequelize:

```
npx sequelize init
```

Answer (score 0):

do as same below It should be work fine
npm install --save sequelize
npm install --save sequelize-cli
npx sequelize init

Comment: 1.npm install --save sequelize
2.npm install --save sequelize-cli
3.npx sequelize init

Answer (score 0):

Try to run this command in your terminal.

`Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).