# Issues when trying to install Socioboard-api NodeJs

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I am trying to install sociobaord 
from the following URL
https://github.com/socioboard/Socioboard-4.0

I tried installing a part of it i.e https://github.com/socioboard/Socioboard-4.0/tree/master/socioboard-web-php and have succeeded

but

I am unable to install the API part https://github.com/socioboard/Socioboard-4.0/tree/master/socioboard-api

**when I am trying to install Socioboard API I am getting following errors**

```
D:\wamp\www\social\user>npm install
npm WARN user@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN user@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.7 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.7: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

audited 877396 packages in 46.139s
found 0 vulnerabilities
```

and

```
D:\wamp\www\social\library\sequelize-cli> ../node_modules/.bin/sequelize db:migrate
'..' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After going through the issue with you .. we came to figure that you need to install all the packages in all the folders as per the documentation.

Also, their documentation is missing that to install the app correctly we need to install sequelize-cli, and preferably to install it [globally](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24521063/9041947).

once installed .. just remove the full link to the sequelize binary *../node_modules/.bin/sequelize* and type `sequelize` instead

Comment: I tried and getting following error `sh : The term 'sh' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ sh ../node_modules/.bin/sequelize db:migrate
+ ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (sh:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException`

Comment: was that through powershell or the usual cmd?

Comment: It is in PowerShell

Comment: unfortunately i'm using linux now, so cannot be tested .. but can you try it like this `..\node_modules\.bin\sequelize db:migrate` as a backslash

Comment: I tried in both CMD and PowerShell but getting errors in CMD `The system cannot find the path specified.` in power shell, the same errors are getting as earlier.

Comment: if you want i can provide anydesk id to get connected remotly

Comment: Yeah sure. where can i send TW id?