# locally installed node.js cli call does not behave like global

Tags: node.js, command-line-interface

scenario:

I have written a cli script. It lives in directory `mycli` and is called `mycli.js` and is shebanged as `#!/usr/bin/env node`.  In the project's `package.json` I have included `"name": "mycli", "bin": "mycli.js"`.

At this point I can call mycli from the project root two ways, either as `$ node mycli` or simply `$ mycli.js`.

After publishing to npm and installing this package globally, I can now call `$ mycli` or `$ node mycli` from anywhere, however, a local install doesn't exhibit the same behavior from its own project root; I have to call the script using the more qualified name, either as `$ node_modules/mycli/mycli.js`, or `$ node node_modules/mycli/mycli`.

Why doesn't `$ node mycli` work in the local scenario?

Comment: Which OS? Directory `mycli` where? What's the actual package.json? Did you npm publish this or is it installed locally from a repo url? (which one? how did you install it?) why does running `mycli.js` work, given that .js files are in no way automatically executable? More exact details, less assuming we know what you're talking about when it comes to your setup.

Comment: edited. perhaps that clears it up.

Comment: if you've used npm publish, what's the package, because that'll help others help you. That said, what do you mean with "local" install? `npm install ... --save` so that it can be used as module? Because if so, that's simply how node modules work. They don't register as global executable unless globally installed.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.org/package/giftwrap

Comment: Yes - local, as in without the -g :) I'm wondering why the local doesn't behave like a local executable when node has put it in the local .bin https://www.npmjs.org/doc/files/package.json.html#bin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the following answer on: [How to use package installed locally in node_modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15157360/316310)

Basically, when you install a package globally, the executable will be found because it's in your PATH. The `node_modules` directory isn't in your PATH by default. Adding every `node_modules` directory on your system to your PATH would get quite messy.

You can check your current PATH with `echo $PATH`. You can add your local node_modules directory (for the lifetime of your session) with `PATH=$(npm bin):$PATH`. The linked answer also has an alternative using aliases.