# NodeJS : can't run package (windows)

Tags: windows, node.js, npm

My PC runs Windows 7 x64, I recently updated NodeJS and since I can't run any packages, I have every time the following error (example with Gulp) :

```
'Gulp' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

I proceeded as follows:
 
I installed NodeJS (node-v0.12.0-x64.msi) the 1st time without uninstalling the old version, the 2nd uninstalling NodeJS.
I rebooted my PC.

```
npm init
npm install gulp --save-dev
gulp
```

Then I get above error ... :(
 
My user environment variables:
 
NODE_PATH

```
%AppData%\npm\node_modules
```

PATH

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Users\{mon_user}\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

System environment variables:
 
Path

```
C:\Ruby200-x64\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\3.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\3.0\bin\x64;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\SWTOOLS\ReadyApps;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Lenovo;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd
```

An echo %PATH% command returns this:

```
C:\Users\{mon_user}\Downloads\cmder\bin;C:\Users\{mon_user}\Downloads\cmder\vendor\msysgit\bin;C:\Users\{mon_user}\Downloads\cmder\vendor\msysgit\mingw\bin;C:\Users\{mon_user}\Downloads\cmder\vendor\msysgit\cmd;C:\Users\{mon_user}\Downloads\cmder\vendor\msysgit\share\vim\vim74;C:\Users\{mon_user}\Downloads\cmder;C:\Users\{mon_user}\Downloads\cmder\vendor\conemu-maximus5\ConEmu;C:\Users\{mon_user}\Downloads\cmder\vendor\conemu-maximus5;C:\Ruby200-x64\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\3.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\3.0\bin\x64;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\SWTOOLS\ReadyApps;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Lenovo;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd;C:\Users\{mon_user}\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run gulp from command line, you need to add -g to install it globally.

```
npm install -g --save-dev gulp
gulp
```

If you don't want to install it globally, you can check this stackoverflow thread : [How to use package installed locally in node_modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9679932/how-to-use-package-installed-locally-in-node-modules)