# Run npm scripts using local deps

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, webstorm, travis-ci

Currently I run npm scripts using local deps this way:

package.json:

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "node ./node_modules/karma/bin/karma start",
    "node-test": "node ./node_modules/jasmine/bin/jasmine",
    "build": "node ./node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp build"
  },
```

I don't want to use global deps, since I can forgot to add deps to the package.json. This way when a local dep is missing, then I got an error message and I don't have problems because some deps are not installed globally, e.g. karma plugins.

Is there a better (shorter) way to define npm scripts using the local libs? Is this travis compatible?

edit:

If it wasn't obvious I have the same libs installed globally, but I want to use the local installs by these projects. That means when I start karma with `karma start` then the globally installed version will start the karma server, which means that if I don't have all of the karma plugins globally installed, then I got error.

Another problem that I have windows, so the solutions described here: [How to use package installed locally in node_modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9679932/how-to-use-package-installed-locally-in-node-modules) do not work. Windows does not recognize the `#!/bin/sh` and the `#!/usr/bin/env node` head sections and there is no sh command as far as I can tell. At least not in webstorm terminal. Git bash has the sh command, but I want to run these npm scripts from webstorm terminal.

One possible solution could be to fix somehow webstorm so it could use sh from terminal. After that I could use `$(npm bin)` I assume. But that's just a guess. I am not sure whether this can be done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

npm automatically puts prepends the path `./node_modules/.bin` to your `PATH` env before it executes commands run by using `npm run` (including the two "magic" shortcuts `npm start` and `npm test`)

[npm scripts docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts#path)

You can just set this up with:

```
"scripts": {
   "test": "karma start",
   "node-test": "jasmine",
   "build": "gulp build"
}
```

Assuming that you have karma, jasmine and gulp-cli listed in either your `devDependencies` or `dependencies` (so that they're install when doing `npm install`)

And yes, it is travis-compatible. Here is an example of a package that is tested on travis using `tap` which is installed locally as a module:

https://github.com/scriptoLLC/couchdown/

Comment: `karma start` started the global karma to me. Which caused error, because some of the dependencies weren't globally installed. That's why I am asking this question...

Comment: if you have everything installed locally it'll use the local version since the path gets added to the beginning.  [In this gist](https://gist.github.com/toddself/ab1ae5c16a038f2f4f84) I've got tap installed globally AND locally.  Then using `which` I ask where it will be running tap from. If i run using `npm test` I get the local version. If I run directly from the command line i get the global version. It will ONLY use the global version if the local version doesn't exist.

Comment: I edited the question. The problem that webstorm terminal on windows behaves differently than the git bash. E.g. it does not have a which command. If I try `which karma` with git bash from the project root I got the global copy. What operation system do you use?

Comment: I am on OSX.  You will not be easily able to run bash/sh scripts on Windows except through various unix-emulation layers (like the git bash you have). Webstorm's terminal is likely either the DOS prompt or powershell. However, the path situation should be the same.

Comment: It isn't on windows, at least on my machine both the webstorm terminal and the git bash loads the global instead of the local. Hmm I might send a bug report about this, but before that I'll update to node 4 from node 0.12. Maybe they already fixed this.

Comment: According to  grassick this is a karma plugin loader related problem: https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/1649 So it does not have anything to do with npm. Can you confirm this?

Comment: By karma you have to install karma-cli https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-cli to be able to run locally from the command line. The other libs don't have this problem as far as I know.