# Zsh: command not found: webpack

Tags: npm, webpack, zsh

I'm learning React and installed webpack through npm to my project directory but zsh is not finding the command even though I can see webpack installed in my project. I used `npm init --yes` followed by `npm install --save webpack`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**EDIT: Don't do this. Bad practice.**

Easy way. Install it globally.

```
npm i -g webpack
```

If you will work with webpack, install webpack-dev-server too

```
npm i -g webpack-dev-server
```

I recommend you first learn a bit about **npm** and then **webpack**.

Comment: Per the documentation: this is not a recommended practice. https://webpack.js.org/get-started/install-webpack/

Comment: @HelmutGranda Thing might be changed since.

Comment: @atilkan It hasn't changed. Webpack docs still recommend not installing globally.

Comment: @atilkan It won't change; global installation of something like webpack is very bad practice. The configuration for webpack is done on a per project basis for good reason and you really don't want a version of webpack to be used other than the presumably tested version installed in your projects package.json. You can end up with broken packages this way. When working with multiple packages you can end up with a situation where they require mutually exclusive version numbers due to differing config which can't be done with a global.

Comment: @Thor84no I agree. The time i wrote the answer that fixed the issue. It was probably zshell issue.

Answer (score 25):

There is no need to install webpack globally.

Try my way:

First, in your package.json file, add this:

```
"scripts": {
   "start": "webpack"
},
```

Then, in your terminal, run

```
$npm start
```

Another quick way:
Just run  (Yes, it is 'npx')

```
$npx webpack
```

That's all.

Answer (score 10):

having webpack installed locally, you could also use:

```
$(npm bin)/webpack
```

instead of:

```
./node_modules/.bin/webpack
```

Answer (score 9):

Installing node modules globally is a quick solution, but i recommend to add `./node_modules/.bin` to the path variable and try to understand, what's the problem.

Execute

```
~ export PATH="./node_modules/.bin:$PATH"
```

Afterwards you can simply use all packages installed locally in your project.
Also commands like `mocha` or `eslint` can be executed without installing these packages globally.
There are several good explanations out there maybe also read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9683472/6817880).

Comment: Don't do that... Putting relative paths in you $PATH variable is a security hole.

See http://stackoverflow.com/a/9683472/1521572

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had this problem with webpack, grunt and gulp and seems that my problem was an issue with permissions.

I installed webpack and grunt globally. However, even then, $ webapack or $ grunt resulted in **command not found**

The problem was that npm installed the global packages to /usr/local/lib/node_modules which required root permissions.

So, to avoid having to use root permissions, I changed the directory in which global packages are to be installed to a directory in $HOME. To do this, I followed this guide:

[Install npm packages globally without sudo on macOS and Linux](https://github.com/sindresorhus/guides/blob/master/npm-global-without-sudo.md)

After this, I installed webpack and grunt globally again (this time without sudo) and verified that they have been installed in my new directory.

Now, I can run without problem!

> $ webpack

and

> $ grunt

Answer (score 0):

if you're on windows, try to get *%USERPROFILE%\Appdata\Roaming\npm* into your path and try again.