# Webpack command not found

Tags: npm, webpack, webpack-dev-server, npm-install

I have installed webpack using

`npm install -g webpack`

and

```
npm install webpack
```

I also installed webpack-dev-server

```
npm install -g webpack-dev-server
```

After completion of installation, I ran the command webpack but, it shows below error

> webpack: command not found

I am not getting what is the error.

Comment: Bishnu you should accept an answer if it worked for you

Answer (score 64):

Your webpack exists in ./node_modules/.bin/ folder . So you should execute this command :

```
./node_modules/.bin/webpack
```

Check out the answer in this thread .

> [webpack command not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38788166/webpack-command-not-working)

Comment: `npx webpack` also does this.

Answer (score 26):

As a good practice is recommended to install `webpack` and `webpack-dev-server` locally, more info [here](https://webpack.js.org/guides/installation/).

```
yarn add webpack webpack-dev-server --dev
# or
npm install webpack webpack-dev-server --save-dev
```

Then you can add these lines to your **scripts** section in your **package.json** file.

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "webpack --progress --colors",
  "start": "webpack-dev-server --progress --colors"
}
```

and finally

```
npm start
npm run build
```

> Note: You need to have a `webpack.config.js` in the root folder to make it run correctly.

Comment: minor correction: --save but not --save-dev. You need webpack also with --production flag.

Comment: @MichaelA.  This  was the reason for webpack build not working on my production server. I had `webpack` and `webpack-cli` in `devDependencies` and both needed to be moved to dependencies for the build to work.

Answer (score 8):

I needed to manually install:

```
npm install --save-dev webpack-cli
```

I guess its needed so that Angular CLI actually understands the commands related to Webpack.

Answer (score 4):

In ubuntu u can try sudo apt install webpack

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use global installation, you can find webpack script in `[node_installed_path]/lib/node_modules/webpack/bin/`, you can use with absolute path, adding to `PATH` environment variable, or symbolic link,  etc.

If you want to use local installation, find it in `./node_modules/.bin/`.

I recommand using local installation ([for same reason about babel](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/#installation)).

Answer (score 0):

You need to be in proper folder to run webpack command.

What I mean by proper folder is folder in which you placed your installed module and module's package.json file.

Cause you installed it with -g parameter it is installed globally and you should find it in: ./node_modules/.bin/webpack.

Best practice is to install modules per project ( folder in which is project) not globally.

Answer (score 0):

webpack -v: webpack command not found

> node -v: v16.14.2
>
> npm -v: 8.5.0

Tried to install webpack globally or locally and a lot of other ways to fix this issue but failed, below solution fixed my case (my case is a little bit special, I reset the prefix as below)

> npm config set prefix "C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm_modules"

**Solution**: add the folder path xxx/npm_modules/ which included webpack.cmd to the System variable Path

[image]

How to find the folder path xxx/npm_modules/ which included webpack.cmd?

> npm config ls

*webpack.cmd* in folder *npm_modules*, you will need this path to be added to System variable Path
[image]

Answer (score 0):

For Linux users, `sudo apt install webpack` worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem within an old project I returned to after a while (that used to run properly). This fixed the issue:

```
npx webpack
```

The version information is: `node v18.16.1 (npm v9.5.1)` and I use a MacOS.