# React Js Environment setup

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm new to react js and I'm trying to set up the environment for it and I followed the steps mentioned in [https://www.tutorialspoint.com/reactjs/reactjs_environment_setup.htm](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/reactjs/reactjs_environment_setup.html).

But after doing all the things mentioned there I'm getting this error:

> 'webpack-dev-server' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [webpack is not recognized as a internal or external command,operable program or batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35810172/webpack-is-not-recognized-as-a-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to develop an application using babel, webpack, etc. You need to follow following steps. No doubt there are much better tutorial available over the internet but it will give you some idea.

**1.Webpack:**

In browsers you can not `require` or `import` modules as you usually do while writing node.js code. With the help of a module bundler, maybe **Webpack,** you can write code that uses `require/import` in the same way that you would use it in node environment. I am assuming you will use `webpack` considering its popularity.

**2. Install dependencies (es6)**

These are minimal dependencies you need in your project (`package.json`) to get it working. You can directly copy paste the following text into a new file named "package.json". run the following set of commands in you EMPTY project directory:

1. install the **node package manager**

   > `npm init`  [follow the command prompt to fill in meta data of your project like name, author,etc.]
2. install **global packages**

   > `npm install -g babel babel-cli`
   >   [this will install transpiler(babel) into your global environment]
3. install **module bundler**

   > `npm install webpack webpack-dev-server --save`
4. install **babel plugins**

   > `npm install babel-core babel-loader babel-preset-react babel-preset-es2015`

After this command set, your package.json will start looking like as following:

```
  {
  "name": "reactjs",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "No Command Written Yet"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.25.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
    "webpack": "^3.4.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.6.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.25.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1"
  }
}
```

**3.Write your webpack-config.js file**

A sample `webpack` config file should like this. Don't ask me about each bit of it but rather have a look on `webpack` tutorial because I can not explain everything here. Just remember the fact that
 `Webpack` is a module bundler that bundles `javascript` and other assets for the browser.

```
    var config = {
   entry: './main.js',

   output: {
      path:'/',
      filename: 'index.js',
   },

   devServer: {
      inline: true,
      port: 8080
   },

   module: {
      loaders: [
         {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',

            query: {
               presets: ['es2015', 'react']
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

module.exports = config;

**4.Set up entry point for your application**

src->index.js

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />
  , document.querySelector('.init')
);
```

**5.Setup index.html in your project root**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <title>Welcome to ReactJs</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="init"></div>
  </body>
  <script src="./public/bundle.js"></script>
</html>
```

**6.Running**

A slight change is needed in your package.json 
replace:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "No Command Written Yet"
  },
```

with

```
"scripts": {
        "dev": "webpack-dev-server --hot"
      },
```

[this will change the script you will run to execute the app bundled by webpack]

Now, whenever you want to run the project, just be in the project root directory and call:

> `npm run dev`

DONE, Have Fun!

Answer (score 0):

Run:

```
npm install webpack-dev-server --save-dev
```

And try again. You got the error because webpack-dev-server couldn't be found in your devDependencies inside of your package.json file

Comment: I am all ears, tell me

Comment: Could you  please send me some reference/link to install the setup.  I would like to do it from the scratch.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you don't have `webpack-dev-server` installed as a global package, that's why you can execute directly.

The recommended way is installing it locally, in this way you'll avoid this problem.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45771708/2666042) you can find the steps to make it run.

Good luck