# sh: 1: webpack: not found

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack

I am developing React+Django application
When I call `npm run dev`

I receive an error

> sh: 1: webpack: not found

```
npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-197-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "dev"
npm ERR! node v4.2.6
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! frontend@1.0.0 dev: `webpack --mode development ./src/index.js --output ./static/frontend/main.js`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the frontend@1.0.0 dev script 'webpack --mode development ./src/index.js --output ./static/frontend/main.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the frontend package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     webpack --mode development ./src/index.js --output ./static/frontend/main.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs frontend
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls frontend
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack --mode development ./src/index.js --output ./static/frontend/main.js",
    "build": "webpack --mode production ./src/index.js --output ./static/frontend/main.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1"
  },
  "description": ""
}
```

Found out that in .`/node_modules/.bin/` i have only `loose-envify -> ../loose-envify/cli.js*`
I read this question [Webpack command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44845143/webpack-command-not-found), but didn't understand how to fix my error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're trying to use `webpack` but it's not listed under `devDependencies`.

In your terminal, run `npm install --save-dev webpack` and then try again.

I may not be 100% correct with that command since I usually use `yarn` and the command is `yarn add --dev webpack` - but I am 100% sure that this is your issue.