# How can I use only locally installed npm packages?

Tags: npm, gulp

For example, to launch *locally* installed gulp, I have to run the following command from inside of my project:

```
node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js
```

To be able to launch npm packages *only* by their name, I want to include *node_modules* relatively to project's root dir. Is this possible?

P.S
I know how to install npm packages globally, but I'm trying to avoid doing that.

Comment: have you tried going into your project directory and install it?

Comment: I have run npm install from my project directory. All packages have been installed successfully. As I already mentioned in the question, running `node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js` does the job. However, running only `gulp` results in `bash: gulp: command not found` error.

Comment: [How to use package installed locally in node_modules?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9679932/how-to-use-package-installed-locally-in-node-modules)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understand you correctly: You are trying to execute programs like `gulp` from your local install.

You can set up a npm script like so in your `package.json`:

**package.json**

```
...
"scripts": {
  "build": "./node_modules/.bin/gulp"
}
...
```

Then, you can run gulp via `npm run build` from your command line. (Or optionally you can type `./node_modules/.bin/gulp`)