# How is a node project's executable automatically available to the shell?

Tags: node.js, npm, bin

I have a `package.json` which includes a `"bin": "./bin/myexecutable"` declaration.

After running `npm install` from within that same folder I can do this `$ myexecutable` and `myexectubale` runs.

`myexecutable` is only available when I am in that directory, and not any subdirectories. I use [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh) normally but the same behaviour happens if I use bash. My $PATH variable does not include the binary.

How is `myexecutable` automatically made available to the shell after `npm install`?

Comment: And there you have it! `:node_modules/.bin:`

Comment: Does installing node add this to the path?

Comment: Maybe. There are so many ways to install node. Some of them probably alters PATH

Comment: Having a look around, it seems not. There is [also a better to way to do that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9679932/how-to-use-package-installed-locally-in-node-modules). Turns out this was a dud question. Thanks for your help. (Do I delete questions like this?)