# How to run npm after installing

Tags: npm

I want to run npm pakage after installing

```
c:/>npm i -g pakagename
c:/>pakagename parameters
```

but I got error 'packagename' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: What did you install?

Comment: Have you tried `npm run packagename -params`?

Comment: I got it adding npm had worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try : `npm install <package-name> -g`

it will install that package globally to your system
then check it by checking its version. like

```
 package --version
```

then do whatever you want
like : https://stackoverflow.com/a/15157360/6747191

Answer (score 0):

To run your installed package with npm you can run it by this command

```
npm run-script <command> [-- <args>...]
```

Alias: `npm run <command>`

According to this documentation: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script