# Transpile with babel CLI

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, command-line-interface, babeljs

I want to transpile several js files that are in ES6 to be compatible with chrome, but it seems the docs in http://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/ are not accurate.

After doing the first few steps I type in the console: `babel` and get:

> You have mistakenly installed the `babel` package, which is a no-op in
>   Babel 6. Babel's CLI commands have been moved from the `babel` package
>   to the `babel-cli` package.
>
> ```
> npm uninstall babel
> npm install --save-dev babel-cli
> ```
>
> See http://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/ for setup instructions.

And even if I run those two commands it mention, I still get the same error.

So my question is how are you supposed to transpile files with Babel and CLI?

Comment: Probably you have babel installed globally, perform `npm uninstall babel -g` (may require sudo)

Comment: I guess it was installed globally, but now I get: `'babel' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.` after rerunning `npm install --save-dev babel-cli` @Andrey

Comment: *"So my question is how are you supposed to transpile files with Babel and CLI?"* Often you create a script in the `package.json`, e.g. `"scripts": { "build": "babel ... "}` and run `npm run build`.

Comment: @FelixKling yes I realize that but I have no idea how to configure babel and webpack with the code I have and their sites aren't very helpful with that.

Comment: Are you on windows OS?

Comment: in your project root as cwd try `./node_modules/.bin/babel-cli --whatever-args`

Comment: @Andrey yes, win 10.

Comment: Doesn't work... no babel-cli in .bin even after I did `npm install --save-dev babel-cli` @Daniel_L

Comment: In Windows, it's a problem to run the local module as binary. You can access local babel as `node_modules\.bin\babel someFile.js`. Maybe this can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9679932/how-to-use-package-installed-locally-in-node-modules

Answer (score 3):

A bit old question, but in case someone ended here through Google like me:

I had the same problem, just ran

```
npm install --save-dev babel-cli
```

in a new and completely empty directory in order to test something and could not transpile when calling babel through npx with the same error. I didn't have Babel installed globally, but after a while I noticed npm didn't create the package.json file. So I deleted everything, created empty package.json with just

```
{

}
```

installed babel-cli again (npm now added dev dependency to the json file) and now it works fine.