# NodeJS: Run dot slash command line Windows

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to get the following code which should execute shell command to wor in OSX and Windows.

```
const exec = require("child_process").exec;
const runCommand = (cmd) => exec(cmd,
    function (error, stdout, stderr) {
        if (stdout.length > 0) {
            console.log(stdout);
        }
    });
```

For the following `runCommand("./node_modules/.bin/someBinary")` it does not work in Windows. But it works fine in OSX. So I wonder what modifications do I need for it to run in Windows as well?

Comment: try backward slashes `runCommand(".\node_modules\.bin\someBinary")`

Comment: is there a windows binary in there?

Comment: whats the current working directory?

Comment: there's no windows binary, but on a Windows system there's *.cmd files in there which supposed to work i think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so in the end I solved it with checking which platform I'm in and in turn I just wrote the same command with OS specific so it would run.

In short I used `process.platform` to find out which OS it is. Not the most elegant. But at least it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered giving a try at [npm-exec](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-exec) ?

> Loads the same environment that would be present for npm run-script , but executes arbitrary bash command lines. (even on windows! Thanks to bashful). This includes modifying $PATH so scripts in node_modules/.bin will be used before global modules.

So you could `npm-exec someBinary` instead of using a relative path breaking Windows / OSX compatibility

If this module does not suit you, you can also give a try at `npm bin` as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15157360/1517335).

Comment: This does not directly solve your problem but I ran into the same issue while working on a gulp file. The most elegant solution I found was to get rid of gulp and use the "scripts" node of my package.json, there you can freely use the command line tools of your project dependencies as your path is automatically filled with the content of `./node_modules/**/.bin/`

Comment: It was same result with `npm bin`. Since I need to wrap it around in something `$(npm bin)/someBinary` and Windows does not recognize the dollar sign...

Comment: @starcorn ok but what about npm-exec ?

Comment: I think there would be same issue with npm-exec. I guess I need to install npm-exec globally. Which isn't an option for me now. So in end I would also need to find its binary inside /node_modules/.bin/ :(