# npm packages not available when installed locally

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, nodemon, npm-scripts

I am working with npm on a web app and I found an issue when using some packages that requires terminal commands to run such like `nodemon` and `concurrently`

I installed it via

```
sudo npm install --save-dev nodemon
```

and when I try to use it via:

```
nodemon ./server.js
```

I get an error

> nodemon command not found

and the same when I used concurrently

I tried also with

```
sudo npm install --save nodemon
```

and it doesn't work.

it only work if I installed it globally

```
sudo npm install -g nodemon
```

Why I can't use it when install locally?

**Note:** I can found the executable file at `node_modules/.bin`

but this following not working as well

```
node_modules/.bin/nodemon ./server.js
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use package installed locally in node\_modules?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9679932/how-to-use-package-installed-locally-in-node-modules)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Global packages can be launched directly because they are saved in your **PATH** directory by default. If you saved a package `locally` you can see it on `node_modules/.bin/` as you mentioned. So there are 2 ways to achieve what you want if you want to run an executable package if installed `locally`:

- You can run it via terminal as `./node_modules/.bin/nodemon yourscript.js`
- Or via npm `scripts` in your `package.json` file, you do this:

  ```json
  {
    "scripts": {
      "nodemon": "nodemon yourscript.js"
    }
  }
  ```

  and execute `npm run nodemon`.

The 2nd approach works for both packages installed globally or locally.

I prefer installing packages locally, so my other apps won't get affected especially if I'm using different package versions per project.

## UPDATE

On [npm@5.2.0](https://github.com/npm/npm/releases/tag/v5.2.0) onwards, it comes with a binary called [npx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npx). So you can run specific packages on the terminal just by `npx [package]` and it executes either your local or global `npm` package. In your case it should be something like `npx nodemon server.js`.

Comment: @PeterWilson try adding `./` before `node_modules` Example: `./node_modules/.bin/nodemon server.js` you don't have to put `./` on your `server.js` script.

Comment: still command not found .. the main issue is to access the `nodemon` command itself not in the path of my script file

Comment: @PeterWilson Did you make sure you have `nodemon` installed locally? try `npm ls --depth=0` and see if `nodemon` is listed. Otherwise you have to install it `npm install --save-dev nodemon`

Comment: yes its installed correctly and I tried your command and I found it

Comment: @PeterWilson any particular reason why you are using `sudo` when installing the package? try uninstalling `nodemon` and then installing the package again without `sudo` and see if it can be found.

Comment: I appreciate your effort, but unfortunately it didn't work too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142400/discussion-between-johnnyq-and-peter-wilson).

Answer (score 4):

Because it's in your node_modules/.bin folder, not your PATH.

You can either use `./node_modules/.bin/nodemon` or `$(npm bin)/nodemon` to call nodemon.

Answer (score 1):

To run any locally installed npm module (Mocha, Eslint, Nodemon, etc.), you can now use `npx`. Try `npx nodemon server.js`.

[image]

I also recommend setting `main` within your package.json to point to the script you want to run (index.js by default), so you could just run `npx nodemon` or `nodemon` (if globally installed) and it will know which script to run.

Answer (score -1):

This is because the local node_modules folder is not in your PATH. See the link to the duplicate question for more details.