# Can I include a folder relative to the current directory in PATH in Powershell?

Tags: node.js, powershell, path, pscx

I run a lot of node projects and often have binaries located in:

`.\node_modules\.bin`

...relative to the projects folder. I'd like to be able to have `PATH` always include these directories, if they exist. I don't want to include other directories, just the one relative to the current directory. I'm familiar with 
`Add-PathVariable` from PSCX and other Powershell basics, but **how do I include a folder relative to the current dir in PATH?**

**Edit**: as mentioned in the question, already, **I expect the path to stay updated as the directory changes**. This is not simply asking about how to use `pwd`.

Comment: You should be able to do this by simply adding ".\node_modules\.bin" (you may have to double the backslashes; I'm never quite sure) to the system PATH.

Comment: `.` is not the same as `$(pwd)`.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Your comment was rude but you're correct: you can add relative folders to PATH (I didn't realise this). Write it and I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: I consider it due diligence here on SO to actually test the subject of a question *before* asking the question. Particularly for someone with almost 30k rep. I do not consider it rude at all when neglect of said due diligence is pointed out. YMMV.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I considered '.' but just assumed '.' would resolve immediately (ie, that it was static rather than dynamic). Re: due diligence: I wrote a somewhat complex script using `find-string` and `prompt` to do this dynamically before you posted your answer-comment. You could have made the same point more politely, likewise I'd expect better from someone with over 100K karma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can use a relative path in Env:PATH and the binaries found will update dynamically**:

Eg:

```
$env:PATH += ';.\node_modules\.bin'
```

Or with the [PowerShell Community Extensions](https://github.com/Pscx/Pscx) (PSCX):

```
Add-PathVariable '.\node_modules\.bin'
```

Unlike using `$(pwd)` the `.` is not immediately resolved to an absolute path, so `PATH` is always relative to the current working directory.

Testing this:

```
$ which uuid
C:\Users\username\Documents\myapp\node_modules\.bin\uuid.cmd
```

Then changing directory, uuid now refers to a program in a different dir:

```
$ cd ..\blog\
$ which uuid
C:\Users\username\Documents\blog\node_modules\.bin\uuid.cmd
```

It's also possible to persistently change `PATH` in the user or system environment:

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable(($env:PATH + ';.'), 'User')
```

or

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable(($env:PATH + ';.'), 'Machine')
```

**Security note**: when entering a command Windows will automatically search all directories in `$env:PATH` for files with one of the extensions listed in `$env:PATHEXT` and execute the first match it finds. Depending on where exactly in the search path you placed `.` that may even supersede system executables.

You may want to take a look at [how to use package installed locally in node_modules](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9679932/1630171) for alternative approaches.