# Running webpack: Webpack command not found

Tags: node.js, bash, webpack

I am following this tutorial - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JdGnYNtuEtE

I installed webpack locally

`npm i -D webpack`

I also installed it globally:

[image]

'npm i -g webpack'

It installed just fine.

My `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "webpack-starter",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Webpack starter project",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^3.8.1"
  }
}
```

The next command he issues is:

`webpack ./src/app.js ./dist/app.bundle`

It worked in the videos but I am getting the error:

`-bash: webpack: command not found`

Why is this happening? Not sure I understand why it isn't working.

Comment: Read that linked duplicate.  You are running into the same issue.  You are not globally installing with `npm -g i webpack`.

Comment: I did it globally as well. Still getting the issue.

Comment: OK, now, is your node install (looks like it's through brew) in your `$PATH`?  Check by running `echo $PATH` and seeing if something like `/usr/local/Cellar/node/7.9.0/libexec/npm/lib/node_modules/` is listed.  Look for anything related to `npm_modules` in path.  That was another thing that that answer talks about.

Comment: I read that is a security flaw. Is that true?

Comment: Cite the source that says that.  If you don't have the directory that contains the webpack binary in your `$PATH`, you can't use `webpack` from the CLI.  You'll have to do what one of the (now deleted) answers said and add `webpack` to your package.json's `scripts` list and run it through there as a package level dependency instead of a global install.

Comment: I think I saw it in the comment section of someone who suggested something similar...i'll find it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9679932/how-to-use-package-installed-locally-in-node-modules/9683472#9683472

Comment: I ended up doing the second option, adding it to a script and npm run build

Comment: You could try one of the other [listed answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45164863/691711), `npx` which ships with npm > 5.2 which checks for package level dependencies before checking path which avoids the security concern.

Comment: Try rehashing your environment variables to reload your path. https://superuser.com/questions/490983/how-to-rehash-executables-in-path-with-bash#490984

Answer (score 0):

Try to install webpack globally by typing `npm install webpack --global` if you want to run it directly via **webpack command**.