# Running node CLI module locally

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, npm-scripts

I am having an node module which is a CLI script. The CLI uses the process.cwd() to get the current directory from which the cli script is invoked( that is important).
This works fine when I install the CLI module globally
(https://www.npmjs.com/package/reduxboilergen)

`npm i -g <module>`

But when I install it locally 
`npm i -S <module>`
Then 
1) The script is not invoked
2) I added a script in package.json  and then if I run npm run "script_name", it is invoked but it always takes the directory from where the npm script is invoked as the process.cwd().
So if the folder structure is

`root
 - src`

Then even if I run it inside src directory its picking up root as cwd() as the package.json is in root.

The node_module npm-run ( https://github.com/timoxley/npm-run)
solves this problem but is there any other way that you experts can think of so that I dont have to add this dependency?

Comment: Please edit your post. It's a bit confusing what you really want. Write some commands that work and not work.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, basically it is kind of a duplicate(which I found now of) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9679932/how-to-use-package-installed-locally-in-node-modules

Comment: The answer would be npx <your_command> as of npm 5.2.0.

Answer (score -1):

The answer would be npx  as of npm 5.2.0