# overriding package.json scripts - NPM

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, yarnpkg, npm-scripts

Is there a way to override package.json scripts? I can't change package.json because it will change it for everyone. i.e in our package we have

```
"script": {
    "dev": "yarn dev:build" 
}
```

I would like to add extra memory for this step as it keeps crashing on my computer. i.e

```
"scripts":{
    "dev": "\"node --max-old-space-size=9000 yarn dev:build\""
}
```

Comment: Create one more script, like `dev:yasin` and specify it with the arguments.

Comment: I can't change the original package.json because it will change this file for everyone.

Comment: it's ok that it will change the `package.json` for everyone, because only you and whoever else might need extra memory will be running that second script (see the @ChetanJadhavCD's answer).

Comment: Another option is to fix you `yarn` command to something else. For example, you could create `~/bin/yarn` with bash shebang and `node --max-old-space-size=9000 /path/to/yarn "$*"`. That way all commands that execute `yarn` from PATH will get the improved memory settings.

Answer (score 1):

You can't "override" `package.json` because the filename is hardcoded in NPM. You can create another script entry like:

```
"scripts":{
    "dev": "yarn dev:build" 
    "devlocal": "\"node --max-old-space-size=9000 yarn dev:build\""
}
```

Exclude `package.json` while committing to whatever SCM you are using, and the modified file would remain local to your machine only.

Having said that, what you are asking for (having another file to do the work of `package.json`), is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

It's not technically overriding a script, but you can execute what would be a script without actually adding it to package.json by calling [npm exec](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-exec) in your terminal:

```
npm exec --max-old-space-size=9000 yarn dev:build
```

Comment: Why installing `npx` when it (a) already comes together with npm by default and (b) it is now recommended to use `npm exec` instead of `npx`? https://stackoverflow.com/a/66604542/3233827

Comment: ssc-hrep3, updated my asnwer.