# How to run locally saved npm packages without setting them on package.json?

Tags: javascript, bash, npm

I am trying to execute a locally saved npm package, but it is not found.

```
npm run jsdoc
```

Outputs:

```
npm ERR! Linux 4.15.0-24-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "jsdoc"
npm ERR! node v8.10.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10

npm ERR! missing script: jsdoc
...
```

But I know the script is located in my `node_modules/.bin`, and can execute it directly:

```
jsdoc -> ../jsdoc/jsdoc.js*
```

And running it works as a pre-configured command on my `package.json`

```
  "scripts": {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    "doc": "jsdoc"                                                                                                                                                                                          
  },
```

Is there a special environment configuration (npmrc or something similar) to make npm run look at both `package.json` scripts and in `node_modules/.bin`?

What am I missing?

Comment: Why do you need to run it via `npm run` instead of just running `jsdoc`?

Comment: I can't install any global packages (-g), and also wouldn't like to have to change package.json for this. I was looking in the aswers in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9679932/how-to-use-package-installed-locally-in-node-modules and I think I figured it out. I got confused by the npm-run answer (which is a package). There is actually no way to run the command locally without messing with package.json, setting the PATH, or going directly to node_modules/.bin. Thanks Charles!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command `npm run` is an alias for `npm run-script`. As seen in the docs:

```
SYNOPSIS
       npm run-script <command> [-- <args>...]

       alias: npm run
```

It will only add `node_modules/.bin` to context inside scripts edited in package.json.

The [npm-run answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40313363/1585933) can be misleading as one can think npm commands could be referenced as git sub-commands would (git-init, git-clone etc), which in this particular case is a separate package, not related to npm run-script.