# NPM and "Concurrently" failing

Tags: npm, command-line-interface, azure-pipelines

Trying to run Protractor/Jasmine e2e tests in an Azure Pipeline. However, I cannot get the tests to run locally using "Concurrently" in my `package.json` file.

Here's the relevant section:

```
"scripts": {
"pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
"e2e": "concurrently -k -s \"dotnet run\"   \"protractor\" SmokeTest.js",
"test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
```

...and the error:

```
>dbm_protractor@1.0.0 e2e F:\Projects\DBM\DBM
> concurrently -k -s "dotnet run"   "protractor" SmokeTest.js

'concurrently' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! dbm_protractor@1.0.0 e2e: `concurrently -k -s "dotnet run"   
"protractor" SmokeTest.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the dbm_protractor@1.0.0 e2e script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely 
additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\David\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-01- 
03T18_19_19_405Z-debug.log
```

The 'pree2e' part runs fine after entering `npm e2e run`

Any ideas please?

Thanks
David

Comment: Global installation seems easiest, but if you don't want to perhaps `npx` preceeding `concurrently`? See [How to use package installed locally in node_modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9679932/how-to-use-package-installed-locally-in-node-modules)

Comment: Or maybe `./bin/concurrently` - I see that there is a `concurrently.cmd` installed into `node_modules/.bin`