# Installing jest with an existing package.json

Tags: javascript, jestjs

So I have a package.json file which I used on a different computer to run javascript tests. Now I have moved to another computer, I have the node_modules folder, package.json, package-lock.json and yarn.lock. If I run npm install in the same folder where package.json is located, shouldn't jest also be installed? Since Jest is located in package.json. If I run jest from  the terminal I get command not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because the node_modules/.bin of your project is not in your `$PATH` try adding it or run `./node_modules/.bin/jest`

Answer (score 1):

To use an npm package from anywhere you need to have it installed globally like this:

`npm install -g jest`

An other solloution would be to add a new script in the package.json like this:

```
scripts:{
   "jest":"jest"

}
```

And the type `npm run jest`

You can also have a look at this question : [How to use package installed locally in node_modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9679932/how-to-use-package-installed-locally-in-node-modules)

Comment: you are welcome hope it helped.If yes don't forget to upvote