# 'testcafe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Tags: powershell, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I'm trying to run testcafe chrome tests/ -e to execute my test but it throws an error saying

```
"testcafe: The term 'testcafe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try 
again.
At line:1 char:1
+ testcafe chrome tests/ -e
+ ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (testcafe:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException"

added testcafe locally to project
```

I'm using Visual Studio Code as IDE and PowerShell terminal for executing commands

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Locally installed packages are not automatically added to the search path. Modern npm has `npx` command.

```sh
npx testcafe chrome tests/ -e
```

should do what you need.

Alternatively you can add your command to npm scripts section as [suggested in the documentation](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/installing-testcafe.html#locally).

Take a look at this question: [How to use package installed locally in node_modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9679932/how-to-use-package-installed-locally-in-node-modules) for the full discussion.

Comment: Thanks Roman!! npx command worked for me but i am unable to connect to URL in my corp network {
 "resource": "XXX/Automation/package.json",
 "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#0",
 "code": "768",
 "severity": 4,
 "message": "Problems loading reference 'https://schemastore.azurewebsites.net/schemas/json/package.json': unable to verify the first certificate",
 "startLineNumber": 1,
 "startColumn": 1,
 "endLineNumber": 1,
 "endColumn": 2
}

Comment: Please submit a new question, so community can see it