# How to use a locally installed Gulp.js v4 with `yarn --no-bin-links`?

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, node-modules, yarnpkg

I added Gulp.js `v4` to the project's dependencies and ran `yarn install --no-bin-links` to install locally.

```
$ yarn install --no-bin-links
yarn install v1.17.3
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
info fsevents@1.2.12: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.12" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
[4/4] Building fresh packages...

success Saved lockfile.
Done in 32.48s.
```

<sub>(I'm using the `--no-bin-links` parameter to avoid this error: `error An unexpected error occurred: "EPROTO: protocol error, symlink '../../../semver/bin/semver' -> '/path/to/project/public/components/accord/node_modules/.bin/semver'"`.)</sub>

The `package.json` defines the correct version ranges:

```
{
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "*",
    "gulp-cli": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp-filter": ">=6.0.0",
    "gulp-less": "*",
    "gulp-plumber": "*",
    "gulp-rename": "*",
    "gulp-watch": "*",
    "html5shiv": ">=3.7.3",
    "jquery": "^3.4.0",
    "jquery-ui": "^1.12.1",
    "jquery-ui-dist": "^1.12.1",
    "path": "*",
    "respond": ">=0.9.0"
  },
  ...
}
```

The `yarn.lock` also refers the correct version:

```
...
gulp@^4.0.2:
  version "4.0.2"
...
gulp-cli@>=2.2.0, gulp-cli@^2.2.0:
  version "2.2.0"
...
```

And also the `yarn list` provides the expected output:

```
$ yarn list | grep "gulp"
├─ gulp-autoprefixer@7.0.1
├─ gulp-cli@2.2.0
│  ├─ gulplog@^1.0.0
├─ gulp-filter@6.0.0
├─ gulp-less@4.0.1
├─ gulp-plumber@1.2.1
├─ gulp-rename@2.0.0
├─ gulp-watch@5.0.1
├─ gulp@4.0.2
│  ├─ gulp-cli@^2.2.0
├─ gulplog@1.0.0
```

But when I now execute `gulp`, old versions (Gulp `3.9.1` and Gulp CLI `1.2.1` are used:

```
$ ./public/components/gulp/bin/gulp.js -v
[15:42:30] CLI version 1.2.1
[15:42:30] Local version 3.9.1
```

**What is wrong here and how to install the required Gulp version locally correctly with Yarn *and* make this version be used?**

Comment: This is related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9679932/how-to-use-executables-from-a-package-installed-locally-in-node-modules

Answer (score 1):

Unless your `PATH` has been customized, running `gulp` on the CLI will always reference the global version if installed.

You need to reference the one installed locally. If you install normally (without `--no-bin-links`) you can use any of these techniques.

1. Create a [yarn script](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run/) such as `"foo": "gulp --version"`. This will reference the local version of gulp.
2. Use `yarn gulp`
3. Use `$(yarn bin)/gulp`

Using `--no-bin-links`, you *can* directly reference the binary, it's just harder because it hasn't been linked to its standard location.

First, you need to find metadata about the binaries associated with `gulp` (actually, `gulp-cli`), which you can do with [yarn info](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/info): `yarn info gulp-cli bin`. Then, you need execute that binary.

```
node ./node_modules/gulp-cli/bin/gulp.js --version
```

The problem with this is it's not safe if the internal organization of gulp changes, so getting the binary linked is a better approach.

You can make it somewhat safer by generating the command with subprocesses, but you still depend on the structure of `node_modules`.