# How to use executables installed in the npm root of a monorepo from anywhere?

Tags: npm, npx

This question ([How to use executables from a package installed locally in node_modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9679932/500902)) asked this years ago, and the correct answer is generally just `npx` these days.  But in a monorepo with multiple subpackages, with different dependencies in each, although it works, it is quite annoying.

```
my_pkg_root/ package.json
   sub_pkg_1/ package.json
   sub_pkg_2/ package.json
   sub_pkg_3/ package.json
```

Or other more deeply nested structures.  If in the root you install `npm i myutils` providing `doit`, then in `my_pkg_root`, `npx doit` just works.  In the subpackages, what `npx` (apparently) does is it first installs `myutils` in the local `node_modules`, runs the script, and then UNINSTALLs it.  Every time.

I want a way that (using npx or other techniques) I can run `doit` in any subdirectory without all the annoying overhead.

Comment: Have you looked at https://www.npmjs.com/package/bin-up

Comment: No.  Although it just changes from having to install the tool everywhere, to having to install `bin-up` everywhere.  Does it work if you install `bin-up` globally?

Comment: yeah seems to work as a global package. Also, I'm thinking that even if I have to install it as a dev dep in each monorepo sub-package, it's much better (from a disk space and version-consistency perspective) than, say, trying to keep "typescript" et al in sync.

Answer (score 0):

Extending the idea from this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/15157360/500902) to the earlier question, if you know the monorepo's root directory name (seems likely, here assuming `/internal`)

```
alias basex='_x=$(pwd); PATH="${_x%%/internal/*}/internal/node_modules/.bin:$PATH"'
```

Then from anywhere in the monorepo, you can do

```
basex doit
```