# Command not found but the module exists

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I have a node module rimraf. It definitely exists based on being able to click on it

and land on its folder under the node_modules. But I get errors saying command not found

for **rimraf**.

Tried to delete the entire node_module.

Also tried following commands.

```
npm ci
```

and

```
npm cache clear --force
npm i
```

No errors, some warning messages about licensing and

No repository field found to a module **drive-module**.

Now when I run following command, I end up with error.

```
npm run build
```

Error

```
sh: rimraf: command not found
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! dyna-modules@0.2.0 build: `rimraf build && bundle-trace-app --clientConfig webpack/client.config.js --serverConfig webpack/server.config.js`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the dyna-module@0.2.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

What would be the issue? Considering that **rimraf** exists?

Comment: What platform are you on (Windows, macOS...)? Have you checked to see if there is a file called rimraf in `node_modules/.bin`?

Comment: If you didn't install it globally it's likely not on your PATH, so run it using `npx`.

Comment: @BenjaminDavies Am on mac. There isn't one. Should there be?

Comment: @jarmod IT's not meant to be global. Is inside my package.json file as a dependency.

Comment: See [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9679932/how-to-use-executables-from-a-package-installed-locally-in-node-modules) that explains options for using `npx` or adding `node_modules/.bin` to your PATH. You should also check that `rimraf` is indeed in `node_modules/.bin`.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can try using this command

```
rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json
```

or delete it manually before re-installing  your node-modules