# How do I run a node lib command without downloading the lib everytime

Tags: javascript, node.js

Currently I am invoking the command...

```
npx @google-cloud/functions-framework
```

But everytime I call this, it downloads the whole library again.

Is there a way I can call this command without having the lib downloaded eveerytime?

Comment: The whole point of npx is downloading and executing. Install the command globally with npm install -g.

Comment: Can I do it without installing globally? Can i just install to a specific directory?

Comment: Sure, but then it'll work only in that specific directory.

Comment: Use npm bin to get the path to the binary files within node_modules, then add this to your PATH. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9679932/how-to-use-executables-from-a-package-installed-locally-in-node-modules