# What is the path to run EJS CLI in an Express app?

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

The [documentation for EJS](https://ejs.co/) says that it comes with a command line interface, and that the executable name is `ejs`.  All of the examples just use `ejs` by itself, and there is no mention of what `PATH` or other environment variables you must establish so that the shell can find that executable.

I am using EJS in an Express.js application.  Thus, I have installed EJS by listing it in the app's `package.json` file.  For example:

```json
{
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "ejs": "^3.1.9",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    ...
  }
}
```

That is equivalent to installing EJS manually via NPM.  For example:

```
mike@doorstop:~/my_app/$ npm install ejs
```

Either way, I end up with a `[app dir]/node_modules/ejs` directory.  There is no file under that directory named just `ejs`.  However, there is a `[app dir]/node_modules/ejs/bin/cli.js` file whose file permissions flag it as executable.  Therefore, I can run the command line EJS using that.

For example, if `template.ejs` is:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <p>Howdy <%= name %>.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

And `data.json` is:

```json
{
  "name": "Mike"
}
```

Then running EJS on that results in what I expect.

```
mike@doorstop:~/my_app/$ node_modules/ejs/bin/cli.js template.ejs --data-file data.json
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <p>Howdy Mike.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

How was I supposed to know that from the documentation?

Further, if I want the app to dynamically generate an HTML file on the server, can I run the command line EJS within a child process of that app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How was I supposed to know that from the documentation?

I could understand your disappointment, but this is a known thing in Nodejs/NPM enviorment. All modules that comes with a binary, when installed in a local project, save their binary under the `node_modules/.bin` directory. From what u wrote, it looks ejs is also saving a JS cli under its specific directory (`node_modules/ejs/bin/cli.js`).
Moreover, you can run binaries with the npx command (included with npm itself).

```
npx ejs
```

By default, npx will check whether  exists in $PATH, or in the local project binaries, and execute that.

Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9679932/how-to-use-executables-from-a-package-installed-locally-in-node-modules)

> If I want the app to dynamically generate an HTML file on the server,
> can I run the command line EJS within a child process of that app?

Yes, you can. But probably I would just use it programmatically. From the [documentation](https://ejs.co/#install) you can see that ejs is not just a cli, but also a library that can be used programmatically.

```
const ejs = require('ejs');
const fs = require('fs')
const people = ['geddy', 'neil', 'alex'];
const html = ejs.render('<%= people.join(", "); %>', {people: people});
// in the html variable, you have the compiled html string.
// now you can use it in any way, maybe you want to save it to a file
fs.writeFileSync('./output.html', html)
// or maybe you are in an express middleware and you want to send the html to the client
res.status(200).send(html)
```