# Cannot create bin executable for my npm package

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm

Based on:

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v10/configuring-npm/package-json#bin

I am trying to create a "binary" for my npm package. My `package.json` looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "@internal/my-exe",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "commonjs",
  "bin": {
    "my-exe": "./dist/src/index.js"
  },
  "files": [
    "dist",
    "README.md"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc --project tsconfig.build.json",
    "ts-node": "ts-node"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "tslib": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "ts-jest": "^29.1.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "^5.0.4"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=18"
  },
  "volta": {
    "node": "18.16.1"
  },
  "publishConfig": {
    "registry": "https://npm.pkg.github.com/"
  }
}
```

and the project (including build output/dist):

```
my-exe
  dist/
    -> src/
      -> index.js
      -> index.d.ts
  src/
    -> index.ts
  package.json
  tsconfig.json
  tsconfig.build.json
```

And **src/index.ts**:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
// eslint-disable-next-line node/shebang
export * from './src/index';
```

I build and pack the above locally with:

```
npm run build
npm pack
```

so I now have:

```
my-exe
  dist/
  ...
  internal-my-exe-0.0.0.tgz
  package.json
```

In another test project I then test that I can install/run the above 'binary':

```
{
  "name": "test-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "devDependencies": {
    "ts-node": "^10.9.2",
    "typescript": "^5.3.3"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=18"
  },
  "volta": {
    "node": "18.16.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@internal/my-exe": "file:../../../my-exe/internal-my-exe-0.0.0.tgz"
  }
}
```

with:

```
cd test-app
npm i
```

And now have:

```
test-app
  node_modules/
    -> .bin/
      -> my-exe
```

so that looks great. But when I try to run it:

```
cd test-app
npm my-exe
```

I just get:

```
Unknown command: "my-exe"

To see a list of supported npm commands, run:
  npm help
```

If I do:

```
cat test-app/node_modules/.bin/my-exe
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
const tslib_1 = require("tslib");
tslib_1.__exportStar(require("./src/index"), exports);
```

So it seems it removed the `#!/usr/bin/env node` when installing it but not sure if that the issue.

**UPDATE**: The above issue was a npm cache "issue" so removing the cache in ~/.npm and deleting the package lock file fixed that when testing locally using npm pack (alternatively update the version each time).

What am I missing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use executables from a package installed locally in node\_modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9679932/how-to-use-executables-from-a-package-installed-locally-in-node-modules)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use the [`npm exec`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v10/commands/npm-exec) command to execute executables located in `node_modules/.bin`:

```bash
npm exec my-exe
```

### Explanation

When you use `npm my-exe`, npm assumes that you're trying to execute a **sub-command**  that's named `my-exe` rather than an executable with the same name, hence it shows this warning:

```
Unknown command: "my-exe"

To see a list of supported npm commands, run:
  npm help
```