# An alternative to package.json, for npm (for globally installed packages)

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a standard `package.json` file for the list of packages that my project is using.

I also need to install some global packages. Instead of doing that manually, I would like to list them in a `global.json` config file, so that I can do:

```
npm install -g -f global.json
```

But the `-f` flag does not seem to exist for npm? Is it possible to specifiy an alternative dependency list, instead of the standard `package.json`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing "global" npm dependencies via package.json](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14657170/installing-global-npm-dependencies-via-package-json)

Comment: @laggingreflex: The "global" part is not really what I am interested about; what I really want is to be able to specify an *alternative* `package2.json` config file (an application of that would be to use it for global packages, but that is just one example). How can this be done for `npm`? Is there any flag to specify the name of the config file, or is `package.json` hardwired (!) into the npm codebase?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The filename `package.json` is actually hardcoded into npm source code and you cannot change it using a configuration option or a command line flag.

While this is not a verified reason from developers, I suspect the reason for not allowing this is that it would break dependency resolution. If package A renames its *package.json* to *myapp.json*, and package B specifies A as its dependency, then npm would be unable to read and install A's dependencies (or any metainformation, for that matter) because of the non-standard *package.json*'s name.

If you [search npm's repo](https://github.com/npm/cli/search?p=2&q=package.json), you will find 100+ mentions both in source and tests that directly reference the string *package.json*.

PS. If your application **requires** a npm module to be installed globally, you should either

1. Clearly state this in README and detect its presence at runtime (and print a nice error message to the user if it is missing)
2. Invest time and effort into making it work with local installation (subjectively preferred)

Comment: Thx. Do you know the rationale behind the decision to make package.json a mandatory filename? Most tools have both a sensible default, and the possibility to override that default with a command line flag ...

Comment: True, but not all programming languages (and their package managers) allow you the luxury of having per-module dependencies, compared to per-application dependencies, i.e. in PHP, you cannot load a module twice, each time with different version because it would cause a fatal error. Whereas in Node, each module may have a dependency and those dependencies may have the same dependency and it all works. I have updated the answer with more info, check it out.