# What's an npm command to install devDependencies globally?

Tags: node.js, installation, package, global

I'd prefer to type a short command, like `npm install -g`, to setup a project's global dependencies, such as node-sass and jshint, than manually typing out `npm install -g every single package`. Is there an npm-idiomatic way to do this?

Comment: There isn't really one. `dependencies` and akin are for packages you intend to `require()`. Global packages you intend to execute from a terminal/shell/etc. are outside the scope of an individual project. You can however install them locally and still execute them: `$ ./node_modules/node-sass ...`

Comment: Sorry. The last bit should be `$ ./node_modules/.bin/node-sass ...`

Comment: related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6480549/install-dependencies-globally-and-locally-using-package-json

Comment: @rha's pointer is still good. That said, I guess a simple script could be written that uses `jq` (?) to extract `devDependencies` and loop over `npm i -g` calls.

Answer (score 3):

You are using `npm install -g <pkg>` wrong here. `-g` indicates, that it's no project dependencies, than rather you global (PC wide).

Those plugins are no devDependencies, but CLI runners. What you want is `npm install --save-dev every single package` upon initialisation. When you need to install those dependencies again you'd just run `npm install` and include something like `./node_modules/.bin/jshint` to your `package.json` scripts in order not to depend on the CLIs.

Answer (score 0):

I get you  are not supposed to do it, but if you still want it, change your global location to make sure you have permissions. Install jq (either download it, or *apt install jq*) and then:

```
export NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX=~/npm-global
cat ./package.json | jq '.devDependencies | keys[] as $k | "\($k)@\(.[$k])"' | xargs -t npm install --global
```

This will create a list of packages and versions from the devDependencies section, pipe that into xargs, and call npm install with them.