# Is it possible to install npm package only if it has not been already installed?

Tags: node.js, bash, npm, circleci

Is it possible to install `npm` package only if it has not been already installed?

I need this to speed up test on CircleCI, but when I run `npm install protractor@2.1.0` etc. it always downloads things and installs them from scracth, however, `node_modules` folder with all modules is already present at the moment of running commands (cached from previous build) and `protractor --version` etc. shows the needed version of the package.

Its perfect to have some one-line command like this:

```
protractor --version || npm install -g protractor@2.1.0
```

but the one that will also check version of the package.

Comment: `[ -d path/to/protractor ] || npm install ...`?

Comment: `command -v protractor >/dev/null 2>&1 || npm install ...`?

Comment: I need check version of currently installed package, preferably not writing full path to the package. multiple different environments, different paths etc.

Comment: @bishop's answer works well when you want to check if something is installed globally

Answer (score 23, accepted):

with bash you can do

```
[ $(node -p "require('protractor/package.json').version") != "2.1.0" ] && npm install protractor@2.1.0
```

Comment: Almost perfect, as it has just turned out. It throws exception if package is not present.

Answer (score 58):

You could try `npm list protractor || npm install protractor@2.1.0`

Where `npm list protractor` is used to find `protractor` package.

If the package is not found, it will return `npm ERR! code 1` and do `npm install protractor@2.1.0` for installation

Comment: Short and simple. Best one-liner here

Comment: I'm on npm v6.0.1 and it doesn't appear `npm list <invalid package>` quits with an error, it just returns a list with "(empty)" in it.

Comment: With the newer npm version, `npm list <package name>` won't show `npm ERR! code 1` but it does exit with an error. Therefore, the whole command `npm list <package name> || npm install <package name>` still works.

Comment: npm list -g protractor || npm i -g protractor@2.1.0 ... if package is global

Answer (score 10):

Function version of the excellent [answer by @JeromeWAGNER](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30668137/2908724):

```
function install_package_if_needed() {
    local p=${1:-Package required}
    local v=${2:-Version required}
    shift 2
    local i=$(node -p "require('$p/package.json').version" 2>/dev/null)
    [ "$i" == "$v" ] || npm "$@" install "$p@$v"
}
```

Use like:

```
$ install_package_if_needed protractor 2.1.0
```

To pass additional options to `npm`, specify them after the version, like so:

```
$ install_package_if_needed protractor 2.1.0 -g
```

Comment: Yeap, thanx. I did something like this, but called multiple system commands from ruby. But exactly this version is not applicable for my task.

Comment: Thanks for this. But needed to remove >/dev/null else $i will always be empty.

Comment: @DarylTeo Thanks! You're right. Not sure what I was thinking. Fixed!

Comment: How can this be generalized to install a package globally, if missing? At the moment it clearly does not accept `-g` flag. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
[ $(node -p "try{require('protractor/package.json').version}catch(e){}") != "2.1.0" ]  && npm install grunt
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue together with wanting to install global dependencies from any "package.json" file requiring them.

This is for a Windows development environment.

[Here is my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34550626/2245849).