# nodejs: install package if not exists (windows version)?

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

In my script I have

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
```

Is there a way to install mysql in runtime (if not installed yet) ?
I read this solution: [Is it possible to install npm package only if it has not been already installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30667239/is-it-possible-to-install-npm-package-only-if-it-has-not-been-already-installed)

But this is done through shell and **not applicable in windows**
I look for a windows version.

My goal is to provide scripts to my client - he is unable to lunch some npm commands to install packages.

Answer (score 0):

```
npm list mysql || npm install mysql
```

`npm list <package>` will return `└── (empty)` (Node.js v10.15.3) if package does not exist.

Comment: yes that seems to work.. but it is very slow indeed