# npm install --global (for all dependencies on package.json)

Tags: json, node.js, npm, npm-install

I would like to install all the dependencies of my package.json file globally. 
I tried Running

`npm install -g`

But this will install the dependencies of the package locally.

Is it possible to install all my package dependencies globally?

Comment: You can read their docummentation:

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install

Comment: The documentations says that using "-g or --global" should do it, but this is not install the packages globally

Comment: It will install on the global scope the specified packages, not the all the packages inside `package.json`, because in there there are 2 scopes: `devDependencies` and `dependencies`.

Comment: I understand that if I send the packages through the command parameters, example **npm install global -g protractor** is going to work. But what I want is to define a list of packages on the package.json dependencies to be installed globally.

Comment: You can do a trick for this. Create a simple js file, create an array for global packages. If this file is called, it will run the command to install all the listed packages in the array, but user need to do for example, `npm install` then `npm run global`. The `global` script you'll reference to the js file.

Comment: I found a very similar question with really good answers. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6480549/install-dependencies-globally-and-locally-using-package-json

Comment: Easier than I though and fault from your part to not searching before.

Answer (score 3):

Save the following content in root of project as package.js

```
let json = require('./package.json')
const ob = json
var a = 'npm i -g '
// @types/slug ^0.9.1
Object.entries(ob['dependencies']).forEach(e => {
    a = a + ' ' + e[0] + '@' + e[1] + ' '
    // console.log(e[0], )
})
const { exec } = require('child_process')
console.log('dependencies', a)
exec(a, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (err) {
        //some err occurred
        console.error(err)
    } else {
        // the *entire* stdout and stderr (buffered)
        console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`)
        console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`)
    }
})


var b = 'npm i -g '
// @types/slug ^0.9.1
Object.entries(ob['devDependencies']).forEach(e => {
    b = b + ' ' + e[0] + '@' + e[1] + ' '
    // console.log(e[0], )
})
console.log('devDependencies', b)
exec(b, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (err) {
        //some err occurred
        console.error(err)
    } else {
        // the *entire* stdout and stderr (buffered)
        console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`)
        console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`)
    }
})
```

now run  node package.js
run it as sudo node package.js if face admin issue