# No entry in the package.json for globally installed module

Tags: node.js

I installed a module with option of `global`. Late on I found no entry of the module in `package.json`. I know there will be an entry without `global` option. I verified that the module was properly responding in command line. How do I add a global module to the `package.json` for the project?

Comment: Install the module normally, `npm install <the-module>`.  Instead of using the globally-installed module, you can (and generally should) run the local instance using npm scripts or using the `npx` command.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Install dependencies globally and locally using package.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6480549/install-dependencies-globally-and-locally-using-package-json)

Comment: `avejidah`, I read the post before posting. The module I installed didn't work without global option (strange).  That's why I was forced to use global.But I didn't find the module under node_modules.

Comment: What's the module that you're installing globally?  Also, when you say "didn't work," what specifically was the issue?

Comment: The module is ipfs, installed with nodejs-mobile-react-native (provide nodejs for react native) on React Native 0.61.5. It is a little complicated.

Comment: In a new folder I run the following: `npm init; npm install --save-dev ipfs@0.40.x; npx jsipfs`  I see the help dialog printed in the terminal.  Does `npx jsipfs` work for you?

Comment: `npx jsipfs` did work and also `jsipfs`. The `ipfs` is installed under `nodejs-assets/nodejs-project` created by module `'nodejs-mobile-react-native`. `nodejs-mobile-react-native` provides `nodejs` environment on mobile platform.

Comment: Seems like a question for the maintainers of the `ipfs` module then.  To answer the question you asked here, installing a global module does not change your project's package.json.  You can't add a global module to package.json, nor should you ever need to.  A goal of package managers is to freeze the project's dependencies' versions, and using global dependencies is antithetical to that goal.